# Getting telephone US local area code with Android

Tags: telephonymanager, android

I would like to know how can i get the device/user area code from within my android app
I know there is a lib named TelephonyManager but i couldn't find the country code feature

To make myself clear:
I have an activity which asks the user to enter his phone number and i want the area code to be taken from the device (from his carrier?)
If i would open my app in new york i would get +212 as the code and a text box to enter my own number

Answer (score 155):

1- Add This Array to Strings.xml File

```
<string-array name="CountryCodes" >
<item>93,AF</item>
<item>355,AL</item>
<item>213,DZ</item>
<item>376,AD</item>
<item>244,AO</item>
<item>672,AQ</item>
<item>54,AR</item>
<item>374,AM</item>
<item>297,AW</item>
<item>61,AU</item>
<item>43,AT</item>
<item>994,AZ</item>
<item>973,BH</item>
<item>880,BD</item>
<item>375,BY</item>
<item>32,BE</item>
<item>501,BZ</item>
<item>229,BJ</item>
<item>975,BT</item>
<item>591,BO</item>
<item>387,BA</item>
<item>267,BW</item>
<item>55,BR</item>
<item>673,BN</item>
<item>359,BG</item>
<item>226,BF</item>
<item>95,MM</item>
<item>257,BI</item>
<item>855,KH</item>
<item>237,CM</item>
<item>1,CA</item>
<item>238,CV</item>
<item>236,CF</item>
<item>235,TD</item>
<item>56,CL</item>
<item>86,CN</item>
<item>61,CX</item>
<item>61,CC</item>
<item>57,CO</item>
<item>269,KM</item>
<item>242,CG</item>
<item>243,CD</item>
<item>682,CK</item>
<item>506,CR</item>
<item>385,HR</item>
<item>53,CU</item>
<item>357,CY</item>
<item>420,CZ</item>
<item>45,DK</item>
<item>253,DJ</item>
<item>670,TL</item>
<item>593,EC</item>
<item>20,EG</item>
<item>503,SV</item>
<item>240,GQ</item>
<item>291,ER</item>
<item>372,EE</item>
<item>251,ET</item>
<item>500,FK</item>
<item>298,FO</item>
<item>679,FJ</item>
<item>358,FI</item>
<item>33,FR</item>
<item>689,PF</item>
<item>241,GA</item>
<item>220,GM</item>
<item>995,GE</item>
<item>49,DE</item>
<item>233,GH</item>
<item>350,GI</item>
<item>30,GR</item>
<item>299,GL</item>
<item>502,GT</item>
<item>224,GN</item>
<item>245,GW</item>
<item>592,GY</item>
<item>509,HT</item>
<item>504,HN</item>
<item>852,HK</item>
<item>36,HU</item>
<item>91,IN</item>
<item>62,ID</item>
<item>98,IR</item>
<item>964,IQ</item>
<item>353,IE</item>
<item>44,IM</item>
<item>972,IL</item>
<item>39,IT</item>
<item>225,CI</item>
<item>81,JP</item>
<item>962,JO</item>
<item>7,KZ</item>
<item>254,KE</item>
<item>686,KI</item>
<item>965,KW</item>
<item>996,KG</item>
<item>856,LA</item>
<item>371,LV</item>
<item>961,LB</item>
<item>266,LS</item>
<item>231,LR</item>
<item>218,LY</item>
<item>423,LI</item>
<item>370,LT</item>
<item>352,LU</item>
<item>853,MO</item>
<item>389,MK</item>
<item>261,MG</item>
<item>265,MW</item>
<item>60,MY</item>
<item>960,MV</item>
<item>223,ML</item>
<item>356,MT</item>
<item>692,MH</item>
<item>222,MR</item>
<item>230,MU</item>
<item>262,YT</item>
<item>52,MX</item>
<item>691,FM</item>
<item>373,MD</item>
<item>377,MC</item>
<item>976,MN</item>
<item>382,ME</item>
<item>212,MA</item>
<item>258,MZ</item>
<item>264,NA</item>
<item>674,NR</item>
<item>977,NP</item>
<item>31,NL</item>
<item>599,AN</item>
<item>687,NC</item>
<item>64,NZ</item>
<item>505,NI</item>
<item>227,NE</item>
<item>234,NG</item>
<item>683,NU</item>
<item>850,KP</item>
<item>47,NO</item>
<item>968,OM</item>
<item>92,PK</item>
<item>680,PW</item>
<item>507,PA</item>
<item>675,PG</item>
<item>595,PY</item>
<item>51,PE</item>
<item>63,PH</item>
<item>870,PN</item>
<item>48,PL</item>
<item>351,PT</item>
<item>1,PR</item>
<item>974,QA</item>
<item>40,RO</item>
<item>7,RU</item>
<item>250,RW</item>
<item>590,BL</item>
<item>685,WS</item>
<item>378,SM</item>
<item>239,ST</item>
<item>966,SA</item>
<item>221,SN</item>
<item>381,RS</item>
<item>248,SC</item>
<item>232,SL</item>
<item>65,SG</item>
<item>421,SK</item>
<item>386,SI</item>
<item>677,SB</item>
<item>252,SO</item>
<item>27,ZA</item>
<item>82,KR</item>
<item>34,ES</item>
<item>94,LK</item>
<item>290,SH</item>
<item>508,PM</item>
<item>249,SD</item>
<item>597,SR</item>
<item>268,SZ</item>
<item>46,SE</item>
<item>41,CH</item>
<item>963,SY</item>
<item>886,TW</item>
<item>992,TJ</item>
<item>255,TZ</item>
<item>66,TH</item>
<item>228,TG</item>
<item>690,TK</item>
<item>676,TO</item>
<item>216,TN</item>
<item>90,TR</item>
<item>993,TM</item>
<item>688,TV</item>
<item>971,AE</item>
<item>256,UG</item>
<item>44,GB</item>
<item>380,UA</item>
<item>598,UY</item>
<item>1,US</item>
<item>998,UZ</item>
<item>678,VU</item>
<item>39,VA</item>
<item>58,VE</item>
<item>84,VN</item>
<item>681,WF</item>
<item>967,YE</item>
<item>260,ZM</item>
<item>263,ZW</item>
</string-array>
```

2-CopyThis Function To your Class

```
public String GetCountryZipCode(){
    String CountryID="";
    String CountryZipCode="";

    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    //getNetworkCountryIso
    CountryID= manager.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();
    String[] rl=this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryCodes);
    for(int i=0;i<rl.length;i++){
        String[] g=rl[i].split(",");
        if(g[1].trim().equals(CountryID.trim())){
            CountryZipCode=g[0];
            break;  
        }
    }
    return CountryZipCode;
}
```

3-Call Function GetCountryZipCode()

4-write Thank you Wais.

Comment: What about CDMA devices?

Comment: Sorry I don't have country names unabridged

Comment: i am using the given method & string array but it is always giving me the ISD code for India.

Comment: @MichaelHerbig AF is for afghanistan not africa

Comment: @Wais It is working in most of the cases I have seen yet but in my app at https://ma9c4.app.goo.gl/rniX , in one of my users phone it returned null, what could be the case/reason ?

Answer (score 30):

Sorry to revive a dead thread, but I spent a while trying to solve this issue so hopefully my response will help someone else.

The example in the original question is confusing, you say you want to append the country code, but give New York area code 212 as an example; That is not a country code it is a local area code. The country code for USA is 1. So you would want the final number to look like "1-212-xxx-xxxx". My answer below explains how to determine the country code, not the local area code.

To get the country calling code for your own number, use getSimCountryIso(). Do not use getNetworkCountryIso(); getNetworkCountryIso will return the country that you are currently located in, but if you are travelling this will return the wrong country. For example if you are from Albania but are travelling in New York getSimCountryIso will return "al", but getNetworkCountryIso will return "us". Obviously if you use the country code for the USA, you have the wrong number.

Now you have a two character country code; for example Canada will be "ca". You can then use this as a lookup key for the table below (obtained from http://www.sikosoft.com/item/international_telephone_country_codes_in_xml_format_using_iso_639-1).

Since country codes don't ever change, it is acceptable to hard code a lookup table in your application. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a direct way to get the user's current country code.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<icc>
    <AF>93</AF>
    <AL>355</AL>
    <DZ>213</DZ>
    <AD>376</AD>
    <AO>244</AO>
    <AQ>672</AQ>
    <AR>54</AR>
    <AM>374</AM>
    <AW>297</AW>
    <AU>61</AU>
    <AT>43</AT>
    <AZ>994</AZ>
    <BH>973</BH>
    <BD>880</BD>
    <BY>375</BY>
    <BE>32</BE>
    <BZ>501</BZ>
    <BJ>229</BJ>
    <BT>975</BT>
    <BO>591</BO>
    <BA>387</BA>
    <BW>267</BW>
    <BR>55</BR>
    <BN>673</BN>
    <BG>359</BG>
    <BF>226</BF>
    <MM>95</MM>
    <BI>257</BI>
    <KH>855</KH>
    <CM>237</CM>
    <CA>1</CA>
    <CV>238</CV>
    <CF>236</CF>
    <TD>235</TD>
    <CL>56</CL>
    <CN>86</CN>
    <CX>61</CX>
    <CC>61</CC>
    <CO>57</CO>
    <KM>269</KM>
    <CG>242</CG>
    <CD>243</CD>
    <CK>682</CK>
    <CR>506</CR>
    <HR>385</HR>
    <CU>53</CU>
    <CY>357</CY>
    <CZ>420</CZ>
    <DK>45</DK>
    <DJ>253</DJ>
    <TL>670</TL>
    <EC>593</EC>
    <EG>20</EG>
    <SV>503</SV>
    <GQ>240</GQ>
    <ER>291</ER>
    <EE>372</EE>
    <ET>251</ET>
    <FK>500</FK>
    <FO>298</FO>
    <FJ>679</FJ>
    <FI>358</FI>
    <FR>33</FR>
    <PF>689</PF>
    <GA>241</GA>
    <GM>220</GM>
    <GE>995</GE>
    <DE>49</DE>
    <GH>233</GH>
    <GI>350</GI>
    <GR>30</GR>
    <GL>299</GL>
    <GT>502</GT>
    <GN>224</GN>
    <GW>245</GW>
    <GY>592</GY>
    <HT>509</HT>
    <HN>504</HN>
    <HK>852</HK>
    <HU>36</HU>
    <IN>91</IN>
    <ID>62</ID>
    <IR>98</IR>
    <IQ>964</IQ>
    <IE>353</IE>
    <IM>44</IM>
    <IL>972</IL>
    <IT>39</IT>
    <CI>225</CI>
    <JP>81</JP>
    <JO>962</JO>
    <KZ>7</KZ>
    <KE>254</KE>
    <KI>686</KI>
    <KW>965</KW>
    <KG>996</KG>
    <LA>856</LA>
    <LV>371</LV>
    <LB>961</LB>
    <LS>266</LS>
    <LR>231</LR>
    <LY>218</LY>
    <LI>423</LI>
    <LT>370</LT>
    <LU>352</LU>
    <MO>853</MO>
    <MK>389</MK>
    <MG>261</MG>
    <MW>265</MW>
    <MY>60</MY>
    <MV>960</MV>
    <ML>223</ML>
    <MT>356</MT>
    <MH>692</MH>
    <MR>222</MR>
    <MU>230</MU>
    <YT>262</YT>
    <MX>52</MX>
    <FM>691</FM>
    <MD>373</MD>
    <MC>377</MC>
    <MN>976</MN>
    <ME>382</ME>
    <MA>212</MA>
    <MZ>258</MZ>
    <NA>264</NA>
    <NR>674</NR>
    <NP>977</NP>
    <NL>31</NL>
    <AN>599</AN>
    <NC>687</NC>
    <NZ>64</NZ>
    <NI>505</NI>
    <NE>227</NE>
    <NG>234</NG>
    <NU>683</NU>
    <KP>850</KP>
    <NO>47</NO>
    <OM>968</OM>
    <PK>92</PK>
    <PW>680</PW>
    <PA>507</PA>
    <PG>675</PG>
    <PY>595</PY>
    <PE>51</PE>
    <PH>63</PH>
    <PN>870</PN>
    <PL>48</PL>
    <PT>351</PT>
    <PR>1</PR>
    <QA>974</QA>
    <RO>40</RO>
    <RU>7</RU>
    <RW>250</RW>
    <BL>590</BL>
    <WS>685</WS>
    <SM>378</SM>
    <ST>239</ST>
    <SA>966</SA>
    <SN>221</SN>
    <RS>381</RS>
    <SC>248</SC>
    <SL>232</SL>
    <SG>65</SG>
    <SK>421</SK>
    <SI>386</SI>
    <SB>677</SB>
    <SO>252</SO>
    <ZA>27</ZA>
    <KR>82</KR>
    <ES>34</ES>
    <LK>94</LK>
    <SH>290</SH>
    <PM>508</PM>
    <SD>249</SD>
    <SR>597</SR>
    <SZ>268</SZ>
    <SE>46</SE>
    <CH>41</CH>
    <SY>963</SY>
    <TW>886</TW>
    <TJ>992</TJ>
    <TZ>255</TZ>
    <TH>66</TH>
    <TG>228</TG>
    <TK>690</TK>
    <TO>676</TO>
    <TN>216</TN>
    <TR>90</TR>
    <TM>993</TM>
    <TV>688</TV>
    <AE>971</AE>
    <UG>256</UG>
    <GB>44</GB>
    <UA>380</UA>
    <UY>598</UY>
    <US>1</US>
    <UZ>998</UZ>
    <VU>678</VU>
    <VA>39</VA>
    <VE>58</VE>
    <VN>84</VN>
    <WF>681</WF>
    <YE>967</YE>
    <ZM>260</ZM>
    <ZW>263</ZW>
</icc>
```

Comment: I'm also looking for answer of question like @Vaiden's. What about CDMA devices?

Comment: What about Wifi devices?

Comment: Sorry but, what kind of XML is this? Where is it expected to go and be handled?

Comment: Into `res/raw`, for instance.

Comment: error in icc. can you please explain the above xml where to put it and how to handle that in code or provide any link to read about that

Comment: My comment is old. My goal was just to explain the difference between country and area codes, and give a pointer in the right direction with a lookup table. Ultimately others have run with this idea and provided much more detailed answers on how to implement this. Please see the answer provided by Alberto. If you will be making lots of lookups and performance is a concern, the answer by Nouman that uses a HashMap is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 17):

This question helped me so much, I want to give you all a class that provide country code from phone code and viceversa.

Usage:

- `CountryCodes.getCode(String country)` returns international code from country sign
- `CountryCodes.getCountry(String code)` returns country signs from international code

An instance of this class can be provided as adapter to Views, for example in Activity onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);    // your layout xml

    Spinner s = ( Spinner )findViewById( R.id.spinner1 );  // id of your spinner
    CountryCodes cc = new CountryCodes( this );
    s.setAdapter( cc );

    TelephonyManager man = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int index = CountryCodes.getIndex( man.getSimCountryIso() );
    if( index > -1 )
    {
        s.setSelection( index );
    }
}
```

What follows is the class code

> CountryCodes.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Call getCountry( String code ) to get matching country sign.
 * Call getCode( String country ) to get matching phone code.
 * It has been extended from BaseAdapter in order to make it compatible with Spinner,
 * ListView and so on (just instance it and give it as adapter).
 * 
 * This class is provided AS IS without any warranty.
 * 
 * @author Niki Romagnoli
 *
 */

public class CountryCodes extends BaseAdapter{

    private static final String[] m_Countries = {
        "AD",
        "AE",
        "AF",
        "AL",
        "AM",
        "AN",
        "AO",
        "AQ",
        "AR",
        "AT",
        "AU",
        "AW",
        "AZ",
        "BA",
        "BD",
        "BE",
        "BF",
        "BG",
        "BH",
        "BI",
        "BJ",
        "BL",
        "BN",
        "BO",
        "BR",
        "BT",
        "BW",
        "BY",
        "BZ",
        "CA",
        "CC",
        "CD",
        "CF",
        "CG",
        "CH",
        "CI",
        "CK",
        "CL",
        "CM",
        "CN",
        "CO",
        "CR",
        "CU",
        "CV",
        "CX",
        "CY",
        "CZ",
        "DE",
        "DJ",
        "DK",
        "DZ",
        "EC",
        "EE",
        "EG",
        "ER",
        "ES",
        "ET",
        "FI",
        "FJ",
        "FK",
        "FM",
        "FO",
        "FR",
        "GA",
        "GB",
        "GE",
        "GH",
        "GI",
        "GL",
        "GM",
        "GN",
        "GQ",
        "GR",
        "GT",
        "GW",
        "GY",
        "HK",
        "HN",
        "HR",
        "HT",
        "HU",
        "ID",
        "IE",
        "IL",
        "IM",
        "IN",
        "IQ",
        "IR",
        "IT",
        "JO",
        "JP",
        "KE",
        "KG",
        "KH",
        "KI",
        "KM",
        "KP",
        "KR",
        "KW",
        "KZ",
        "LA",
        "LB",
        "LI",
        "LK",
        "LR",
        "LS",
        "LT",
        "LU",
        "LV",
        "LY",
        "MA",
        "MC",
        "MD",
        "ME",
        "MG",
        "MH",
        "MK",
        "ML",
        "MM",
        "MN",
        "MO",
        "MR",
        "MT",
        "MU",
        "MV",
        "MW",
        "MX",
        "MY",
        "MZ",
        "NA",
        "NC",
        "NE",
        "NG",
        "NI",
        "NL",
        "NO",
        "NP",
        "NR",
        "NU",
        "NZ",
        "OM",
        "PA",
        "PE",
        "PF",
        "PG",
        "PH",
        "PK",
        "PL",
        "PM",
        "PN",
        "PR",
        "PT",
        "PW",
        "PY",
        "QA",
        "RO",
        "RS",
        "RU",
        "RW",
        "SA",
        "SB",
        "SC",
        "SD",
        "SE",
        "SG",
        "SH",
        "SI",
        "SK",
        "SL",
        "SM",
        "SN",
        "SO",
        "SR",
        "ST",
        "SV",
        "SY",
        "SZ",
        "TD",
        "TG",
        "TH",
        "TJ",
        "TK",
        "TL",
        "TM",
        "TN",
        "TO",
        "TR",
        "TV",
        "TW",
        "TZ",
        "UA",
        "UG",
        "US",
        "UY",
        "UZ",
        "VA",
        "VE",
        "VN",
        "VU",
        "WF",
        "WS",
        "YE",
        "YT",
        "ZA",
        "ZM",
        "ZW"
    };

    private static final String[] m_Codes = {
        "376",
        "971",
        "93",
        "355",
        "374",
        "599",
        "244",
        "672",
        "54",
        "43",
        "61",
        "297",
        "994",
        "387",
        "880",
        "32",
        "226",
        "359",
        "973",
        "257",
        "229",
        "590",
        "673",
        "591",
        "55",
        "975",
        "267",
        "375",
        "501",
        "1",
        "61",
        "243",
        "236",
        "242",
        "41",
        "225",
        "682",
        "56",
        "237",
        "86",
        "57",
        "506",
        "53",
        "238",
        "61",
        "357",
        "420",
        "49",
        "253",
        "45",
        "213",
        "593",
        "372",
        "20",
        "291",
        "34",
        "251",
        "358",
        "679",
        "500",
        "691",
        "298",
        "33",
        "241",
        "44",
        "995",
        "233",
        "350",
        "299",
        "220",
        "224",
        "240",
        "30",
        "502",
        "245",
        "592",
        "852",
        "504",
        "385",
        "509",
        "36",
        "62",
        "353",
        "972",
        "44",
        "91",
        "964",
        "98",
        "39",
        "962",
        "81",
        "254",
        "996",
        "855",
        "686",
        "269",
        "850",
        "82",
        "965",
        "7",
        "856",
        "961",
        "423",
        "94",
        "231",
        "266",
        "370",
        "352",
        "371",
        "218",
        "212",
        "377",
        "373",
        "382",
        "261",
        "692",
        "389",
        "223",
        "95",
        "976",
        "853",
        "222",
        "356",
        "230",
        "960",
        "265",
        "52",
        "60",
        "258",
        "264",
        "687",
        "227",
        "234",
        "505",
        "31",
        "47",
        "977",
        "674",
        "683",
        "64",
        "968",
        "507",
        "51",
        "689",
        "675",
        "63",
        "92",
        "48",
        "508",
        "870",
        "1",
        "351",
        "680",
        "595",
        "974",
        "40",
        "381",
        "7",
        "250",
        "966",
        "677",
        "248",
        "249",
        "46",
        "65",
        "290",
        "386",
        "421",
        "232",
        "378",
        "221",
        "252",
        "597",
        "239",
        "503",
        "963",
        "268",
        "235",
        "228",
        "66",
        "992",
        "690",
        "670",
        "993",
        "216",
        "676",
        "90",
        "688",
        "886",
        "255",
        "380",
        "256",
        "1",
        "598",
        "998",
        "39",
        "58",
        "84",
        "678",
        "681",
        "685",
        "967",
        "262",
        "27",
        "260",
        "263"
    };

    private Context m_Context;

    public CountryCodes( Context cxt )
    {
        super();

        m_Context = cxt;
    }

    /**
     * Get phone code from country sign.
     * 
     * @param country: two-chars country sign to fetch ("US", "IT", "GB", ...)
     * @return string of matching phone code ("1", "39", "44", ...). null if none matches.
     */
    public static String getCode( String country )
    {
        int index = getIndex( country );
        return index == -1? null: getCode(index);
    }

    /**
     * Get international code at provided index.
     * 
     * @param index: array index
     * @return international code
     */
    public static String getCode( int index )
    {
        return m_Codes[index];
    }

    /**
     * Get country signs from phone code.
     * More countries may match the same code. 
     * 
     * @param code: phone code to fetch ("1", "39", "44", ...)
     * @return list of uppercase country signs (["US","PR","CA"], ["IT","VA"], ["GB","IM"], ...)
     *          Empty list if none matches.
     */
    public static ArrayList<String> getCountry( String code )
    {
        ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
        getCountry(code, matches);
        return matches;
    }

    /**
     * Memory cheap version of country fetching: uses user provided list as output which outside 
     * could be recycled on desire.
     * 
     * @param code: country sign to fetch
     * @param matches: list to fill with matches, used as output
     */
    public static void getCountry( String code, ArrayList<String> matches )
    {
        matches.clear();

        for( int i=0; i<m_Codes.length; ++i )
            if( m_Codes[i].equals( code ) )
                matches.add(getCountry(i));
    }

    /**
     * Returns country sign at specified index of internal array.
     * 
     * @param index: index to fetch
     * @return country sign
     */
    public static String getCountry( int index )
    {
        return m_Countries[index];
    }

    /**
     * Looks for country sign array index.
     * 
     * @param country: country sign to search
     * @return array index. -1 if none matches.
     */
    public static int getIndex( String country )
    {
        String search = country.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());

        for( int i=0; i<m_Countries.length; ++i )
            if( m_Countries[i].equals( search ) )
                return i;

        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return m_Codes.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return m_Countries[index];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int index) {
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View recycleView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        TextView view;
        if( recycleView == null )
        {
            view = new TextView(m_Context);
            view.setPadding(30, 10, 10, 10);
        }
        else
        {
            view = (TextView)recycleView;
        }

        view.setText(m_Countries[index]);

        return view;
    }
}
```

I'm using it and seems to work but, you know, just death and taxes are certain. Feel free to customize it and suggest fixes.

HTH

Comment: This works as well but the 2-arrays design is bad. What if I want to add a new country code? If I want to keep it alphabetized I'm risking in messing up everything.
The design of the single array, which is more similar to a dictionary, is much better.

Comment: @amitfr fair enough, but I took the assumption that countries doesn't change so often to require a dynamic storage. Beyond this, I feel like native Java arrays to be "faster" than dictionaries (but not benchmarked at all!).

Answer (score 14):

Use `compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.0.1'` dependency. This makes the task easy and provides accurate result because it's by google.

[Here](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) you can know more about it.

## The output I m getting is something like this:

[image]

Here I m using spinner.

## 1) I have created a custom Adapter CountryCodesAdapter:

```
package com.amitupadhyay.getcountrycode;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by aupadhyay on 1/24/17.
 */

public class CountryCodesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final List<CountryCode> mData;
    private final int mViewId;
    private final int mDropdownViewId;
    private int mSelected;

    public static final class CountryCode implements Comparable<String> {
        public String regionCode;
        public int countryCode;
        public String regionName;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(String another) {
            return regionCode != null && another != null ? regionCode.compareTo(another) : 1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o)
                return true;

            if (o != null && o instanceof CountryCode) {
                CountryCode other = (CountryCode) o;

                return regionCode != null &&
                        regionCode.equals(other.regionCode);
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return regionCode;
        }
    }

    public CountryCodesAdapter(Context context, int viewId, int dropdownViewId) {
        this(context, new ArrayList<CountryCode>(), viewId, dropdownViewId);
    }

    public CountryCodesAdapter(Context context, List<CountryCode> data, int viewId, int dropdownViewId) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mData = data;
        mViewId = viewId;
        mDropdownViewId = dropdownViewId;
    }

    public void add(CountryCode entry) {
        mData.add(entry);
    }

    public void add(String regionCode) {
        CountryCode cc = new CountryCode();
        cc.regionCode = regionCode;
        cc.countryCode = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().getCountryCodeForRegion(regionCode);
        cc.regionName = getRegionDisplayName(regionCode, Locale.getDefault());
        mData.add(cc);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mData.clear();
    }

    public void sort(Comparator<? super CountryCode> comparator) {
        Collections.sort(mData, comparator);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        CountryCode e = mData.get(position);
        return (e != null) ? e.countryCode : -1;
    }

    public int getPositionForId(CountryCode cc) {
        return cc != null ? mData.indexOf(cc) : -1;
    }

    public void setSelected(int position) {
        mSelected = position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CheckedTextView textView;
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(mDropdownViewId, parent, false);
            textView = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            view.setTag(textView);
        }
        else {
            view = convertView;
            textView = (CheckedTextView) view.getTag();
        }

        CountryCode e = mData.get(position);

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(5)
                .append(e.regionName)
                .append(" (+")
                .append(e.countryCode)
                .append(')');

        textView.setText(text);
        textView.setChecked((mSelected == position));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView;
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(mViewId, parent, false);
            textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            view.setTag(textView);
        }
        else {
            view = convertView;
            textView = (TextView) view.getTag();
        }

        CountryCode e = mData.get(position);

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(3)
                .append('+')
                .append(e.countryCode)
                .append(" (")
                .append(e.regionName)
                .append(')');

        textView.setText(text);

        return view;
    }

    /** Returns the localized region name for the given region code. */
    public String getRegionDisplayName(String regionCode, Locale language) {
        return (regionCode == null || regionCode.equals("ZZ") ||
                regionCode.equals(PhoneNumberUtil.REGION_CODE_FOR_NON_GEO_ENTITY))
                ? "" : new Locale("", regionCode).getDisplayCountry(language);
    }
}
```

## 2) Now the layout of my Activity where I am displaying the spinner of country code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_simple"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="18dip" >

            <Spinner android:id="@+id/phone_cc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phone_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_validation_number"
                android:inputType="phone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_validate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/button_validate" />

           </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

## 3) java Activity code is below:

```
package com.amitupadhyay.getcountrycode;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.amitupadhyay.getcountrycode.CountryCodesAdapter.CountryCode;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.Phonenumber;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;

public class NumberValidation extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner mCountryCode;
    private EditText mPhone;
    private Button mValidateButton;

    /**
     * Compatibility method for {@link PhoneNumberUtil#getSupportedRegions()}.
     * This was introduced because crappy Honeycomb has an old version of
     * libphonenumber, therefore Dalvik will insist on we using it.
     * In case getSupportedRegions doesn't exist, getSupportedCountries will be
     * used.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Set<String> getSupportedRegions(PhoneNumberUtil util) {
        try {
            return (Set<String>) util.getClass()
                    .getMethod("getSupportedRegions")
                    .invoke(util);
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            try {
                return (Set<String>) util.getClass()
                        .getMethod("getSupportedCountries")
                        .invoke(util);
            }
            catch (Exception helpme) {
                // ignored
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // ignored
        }
        return new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.number_validation);
        //setupToolbar(false);

        mCountryCode = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.phone_cc);
        mPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        mValidateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_validate);

        // populate country codes
        final CountryCodesAdapter ccList = new CountryCodesAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        PhoneNumberUtil util = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
        Set<String> ccSet = getSupportedRegions(util);
        for (String cc : ccSet)
            ccList.add(cc);

        ccList.sort(new Comparator<CountryCodesAdapter.CountryCode>() {
            public int compare(CountryCodesAdapter.CountryCode lhs, CountryCodesAdapter.CountryCode rhs) {
                return lhs.regionName.compareTo(rhs.regionName);
            }
        });
        mCountryCode.setAdapter(ccList);
        mCountryCode.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ccList.setSelected(position);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        // FIXME this doesn't consider creation because of configuration change
        Phonenumber.PhoneNumber myNum = getMyNumber(this);
        if (myNum != null) {
            CountryCode cc = new CountryCode();
            cc.regionCode = util.getRegionCodeForNumber(myNum);
            if (cc.regionCode == null)
                cc.regionCode = util.getRegionCodeForCountryCode(myNum.getCountryCode());
            mCountryCode.setSelection(ccList.getPositionForId(cc));
            mPhone.setText(String.valueOf(myNum.getNationalNumber()));
        }
        else {
            final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            final String regionCode = tm.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase(Locale.US);
            CountryCode cc = new CountryCode();
            cc.regionCode = regionCode;
            cc.countryCode = util.getCountryCodeForRegion(regionCode);
            mCountryCode.setSelection(ccList.getPositionForId(cc));
        }
    }

    /** Returns the (parsed) number stored in this device SIM card. */
    @SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
    public Phonenumber.PhoneNumber getMyNumber(Context context) {
        try {
            final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            final String regionCode = tm.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase(Locale.US);
            return PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().parse(tm.getLine1Number(), regionCode);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

## Few extra features:

a) Your country will get automatically selected in the spinner.

To achieve I have used this:

```
 Phonenumber.PhoneNumber myNum = getMyNumber(this);
        if (myNum != null) {
            CountryCode cc = new CountryCode();
            cc.regionCode = util.getRegionCodeForNumber(myNum);
            if (cc.regionCode == null)
                cc.regionCode = util.getRegionCodeForCountryCode(myNum.getCountryCode());
            mCountryCode.setSelection(ccList.getPositionForId(cc));
            mPhone.setText(String.valueOf(myNum.getNationalNumber()));
        }
        else {
            final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            final String regionCode = tm.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase(Locale.US);
            CountryCode cc = new CountryCode();
            cc.regionCode = regionCode;
            cc.countryCode = util.getCountryCodeForRegion(regionCode);
            mCountryCode.setSelection(ccList.getPositionForId(cc));
        }
```

I think this method is little better than other ways listed here. So I posted this. Hope someone may find it helpful :-)

This project on GitHub is [here](https://github.com/amit-upadhyay-IT/GetCountryCode)

Answer (score 6):

in this case this would look like:

```
    /**
     * network iso code: referred and listed at:
     * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_country_codes
     */
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Constants.DEVICE_COUNTRY = manager.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

So nobody has to look and double-check (context is a local variable of a valid Context object).
Constants.DEVICE_COUNTRY is of Type String :) (just a variable)

Comment: This is incorrect. getNetworkCountryIso specifically states it returns the MCC; It is completely different than the country calling code. What they are looking for is the ITU country code. For example the MCC for Canada is 302, but the calling code (ITU code) is 1. I am also looking at how to get the ITU code but am unable to.

Comment: constant is just a variable http://ragefaces.s3.amazonaws.com/5041f66dae7c704fdb000001/genius.png

Answer (score 3):

add these to the string.xml 
Enjoy:)

```
<string-array name="country_code">
            <item></item>
             <item>
                +93

            </item>
            <item>
               +355
            </item>
            <item>
                +213
            </item>
            <item>
                +1684
            </item>
            <item>
                +376
            </item>
            <item>
                +244
            </item>
            <item>
                +1264
            </item>
            <item>
                +672
            </item>
            <item>
                +1268
            </item>
            <item>
                +54
            </item>
            <item>
                +374
            </item>
            <item>
              +297
            </item>
            <item>
                +61
            </item>
            <item>
                +43
            </item>
            <item>
                +994
            </item>
            <item>
                +1242
            </item>
            <item>
                +973
            </item>
            <item>
                +880
            </item>
            <item>
                +1246
            </item>
            <item>
               +375
            </item>
            <item>
                +32
            </item>
            <item>
                +501
            </item>
            <item>
                +229
            </item>
            <item>
                +1441
            </item>
            <item>
                +975
            </item>
            <item>
                +591
            </item>
            <item>
                +387
            </item>
            <item>
                +267
            </item>
            <item>
                +55
            </item>
            <item>
                +246
            </item>
            <item>
                +1284
            </item>
            <item>
                +673
            </item>
            <item>
                +359
            </item>
            <item>
                +226
            </item>
            <item>
                +257
            </item>
            <item>
                +855
            </item>
            <item>
                +237
            </item>
            <item>
                +1
            </item>
            <item>
                +238
            </item>
            <item>
                +1345
            </item>
            <item>
                +236
            </item>
            <item>
                +235
            </item>
            <item>
                +56
            </item>
            <item>
               +86
            </item>
            <item>
                +61
            </item>
            <item>
                +61
            </item>
            <item>
                +57
            </item>
            <item>
                +269
            </item>
            <item>
                +682
            </item>
            <item>
                +506
            </item>
            <item>
                +385
            </item>
            <item>
                +53
            </item>
            <item>
                +599
            </item>
            <item>
                +357
            </item>
            <item>
                +420
            </item>
            <item>
                +243
            </item>
            <item>
               +45
            </item>
            <item>
                +253
            </item>
            <item>
                +1767
            </item>
            <item>
                +1809
            </item>
            <item>
                +670
            </item>
            <item>
                +593
            </item>
            <item>
                +20
            </item>
            <item>
               +503
            </item>
            <item>
               +240
            </item>
            <item>
                +291
            </item>
            <item>
                +372
            </item>
            <item>
                +251
            </item>
            <item>
                +500
            </item>
            <item>
                +298
            </item>
            <item>
               +679
            </item>
            <item>
                +358
            </item>
            <item>
                +33
            </item>
            <item>
                +689
            </item>
            <item>
                +241
            </item>
            <item>
                +220
            </item>
            <item>
                +995
            </item>
            <item>
               +49
            </item>
            <item>
                +233
            </item>
            <item>
                +350
            </item>
            <item>
                +30
            </item>
            <item>
                +299
            </item>
            <item>
               +1473
            </item>
            <item>
                +1671
            </item>
            <item>
                +502
            </item>
            <item>
                +441481
            </item>
            <item>
               +224
            </item>
            <item>
                +245
            </item>
            <item>
                +592
            </item>
            <item>
                +509
            </item>
            <item>
                +504
            </item>
            <item>
               +852
            </item>
            <item>
                +36
            </item>
            <item>
                +354
            </item>
            <item>
               +91
            </item>
            <item>
                +62
            </item>
            <item>
                +98
            </item>
            <item>
               +964
            </item>
            <item>
                +53
            </item>
            <item>
             +441624
            </item>
            <item>
               +972
            </item>
            <item>
                +39
            </item>
            <item>
               +225
            </item>
            <item>
               +1876
            </item>
            <item>
                +81
            </item>
            <item>
                +441534
            </item>
            <item>
                +962
            </item>
            <item>
               +7
            </item>
            <item>
                +254
            </item>
            <item>
               +686
            </item>
            <item>
                +383
            </item>
            <item>
                +965
            </item>
            <item>
               +996
            </item>
            <item>
                +856
            </item>
            <item>
               +371
            </item>
            <item>
                +961
            </item>
            <item>
                +266
            </item>
            <item>
                +231
            </item>
            <item>
                +218
            </item>
            <item>
               +423
            </item>
            <item>
              +370
            </item>
            <item>
                +352
            </item>
            <item>
                +853
            </item>
            <item>
               +389
            </item>
            <item>
               +261
            </item>
            <item>
              +265
            </item>
            <item>
               +60
            </item>
            <item>
               +960
            </item>
            <item>
                +223
            </item>
            <item>
                +356
            </item>
            <item>
                +692
            </item>
            <item>
              +222
            </item>
            <item>
               +230
            </item>
            <item>
               +262
            </item>
            <item>
               +52
            </item>
            <item>
               +691
            </item>
            <item>
               +373
            </item>
            <item>
             +377
            </item>
            <item>
                +976
            </item>
            <item>
                +382
            </item>
            <item>
               +1664
            </item>
            <item>
                +212
            </item>
            <item>
                +258
            </item>
            <item>
              +95
            </item>
            <item>
               +264
            </item>
            <item>
                +674
            </item>
            <item>
               +977
            </item>
            <item>
                +31
            </item>
            <item>
                +599
            </item>
            <item>
                +687
            </item>
            <item>
              +64

            </item>
            <item>
                +505
            </item>
            <item>
                +227
            </item>
            <item>
                +234
            </item>
            <item>
                +683
            </item>
            <item>
                +850
            </item>
            <item>
                +1670
            </item>
            <item>
                +47
            </item>
            <item>
               +968
            </item>
            <item>
               +92
            </item>
            <item>
                +680
            </item>
            <item>
                +970
            </item>
            <item>
                +507
            </item>
            <item>
                +675
            </item>
            <item>
                +595
            </item>
            <item>
               +51
            </item>
            <item>
               +63
            </item>
            <item>
               +64
            </item>
            <item>
                +48
            </item>
            <item>
                +351
            </item>
            <item>
               +1787
            </item>
            <item>
                +974
            </item>
            <item>
               +242
            </item>
            <item>
                +262
            </item>
            <item>
               +40
            </item>
            <item>
              +7
            </item>
            <item>
                +250
            </item>
            <item>
                +590
            </item>
            <item>
                +290
            </item>
            <item>
                +1869
            </item>
            <item>
                +1758
            </item>
            <item>
                +590
            </item>
            <item>
                +508
            </item>
            <item>
                +1784
            </item>
            <item>
                +685
            </item>
            <item>
                +378
            </item>
            <item>
                +239
            </item>
            <item>
                +966
            </item>
            <item>
                +221
            </item>
            <item>
                +381
            </item>
            <item>
                +248
            </item>
            <item>
               +232
            </item>
            <item>
               +65
            </item>
            <item>
               +1721
            </item>
            <item>
                +421
            </item>
            <item>
                +386
            </item>
            <item>
                +677
            </item>
            <item>
                +252
            </item>
            <item>
              +27
            </item>
            <item>
               +82
            </item>
            <item>
               +211
            </item>
            <item>
               +34
            </item>
            <item>
                +94
            </item>
            <item>
              +249
            </item>
            <item>
             +597
            </item>
            <item>
               +47
            </item>
            <item>
                +268
            </item>
            <item>
               +46
            </item>
            <item>
                +41
            </item>
            <item>
               +963
            </item>
            <item>
                +886
            </item>
            <item>
                +992
            </item>
            <item>
                +255
            </item>
            <item>
               +66
            </item>
            <item>
                +228
            </item>
            <item>
               +690
            </item>
            <item>
                +676
            </item>
            <item>
               +1868
            </item>
            <item>
               +216
            </item>
            <item>
                +90
            </item>
            <item>
               +993
            </item>
            <item>
                +1649
            </item>
            <item>
                +688
            </item>
            <item>
                +1340
            </item>
            <item>
                +256
            </item>
            <item>
                +380
            </item>
            <item>
               +971
            </item>
            <item>
                +44
            </item>
            <item>
                +1
            </item>
            <item>
               +598
            </item>
            <item>
                +998
            </item>
            <item>
                +678
            </item>
            <item>
                +379
            </item>
            <item>
                +58
            </item>
            <item>
                +84
            </item>
            <item>
               +681
            </item>
            <item>
                +212
            </item>
            <item>
                967
            </item>
            <item>
                260
            </item>
            <item>
                263
            </item>
        </string-array>
        <string-array name="country_arrays">
            <item>Code</item>
            <item>Afghanistan</item>
            <item>Albania</item>
            <item>Algeria</item>
            <item>American Samoa</item>
            <item>Andorra</item>
            <item>Angola</item>
            <item>Anguilla</item>
            <item>Antarctica</item>
            <item>Antigua and Barbuda</item>
            <item>Argentina</item>
            <item>Armenia</item>
            <item>Aruba</item>
            <item>Australia</item>
            <item>Austria</item>
            <item>Azerbaijan</item>
            <item>Bahrain</item>
            <item>Bangladesh</item>
            <item>Barbados</item>
            <item>Belarus</item>
            <item>Belgium</item>
            <item>Belize</item>
            <item>Benin</item>
            <item>Bermuda</item>
            <item>Bhutan</item>
            <item>Bolivia</item>
            <item>Bosnia and Herzegovina</item>
            <item>Botswana</item>
            <item>Bouvet Island</item>
            <item>Brazil</item>
            <item>British Indian Ocean Territory</item>
            <item>British Virgin Islands</item>
            <item>Brunei</item>
            <item>Bulgaria</item>
            <item>Burkina Faso</item>
            <item>Burundi</item>
            <item>Cambodia</item>
            <item>Cameroon</item>
            <item>Canada</item>
            <item>Cape Verde</item>
            <item>Cayman Islands</item>
            <item>Central African Republic</item>
            <item>Chad</item>
            <item>Chile</item>
            <item>China</item>
            <item>Christmas Island</item>
            <item>Cocos (Keeling) Islands</item>
            <item>Colombia</item>
            <item>Comoros</item>
            <item>Congo</item>
            <item>Cook Islands</item>
            <item>Costa Rica</item>
            <item>Cote d\'Ivoire</item>
            <item>Croatia</item>
            <item>Cuba</item>
            <item>Cyprus</item>
            <item>Czech Republic</item>
            <item>Democratic Republic of the Congo</item>
            <item>Denmark</item>
            <item>Djibouti</item>
            <item>Dominica</item>
            <item>Dominican Republic</item>
            <item>East Timor</item>
            <item>Ecuador</item>
            <item>Egypt</item>
            <item>El Salvador</item>
            <item>Equatorial Guinea</item>
            <item>Eritrea</item>
            <item>Estonia</item>
            <item>Ethiopia</item>
            <item>Faeroe Islands</item>
            <item>Falkland Islands</item>
            <item>Fiji</item>
            <item>Finland</item>
            <item>Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia</item>
            <item>France</item>
            <item>French Guiana</item>
            <item>French Polynesia</item>
            <item>French Southern Territories</item>
            <item>Gabon</item>
            <item>Georgia</item>
            <item>Germany</item>
            <item>Ghana</item>
            <item>Gibraltar</item>
            <item>Greece</item>
            <item>Greenland</item>
            <item>Grenada</item>
            <item>Guadeloupe</item>
            <item>Guam</item>
            <item>Guatemala</item>
            <item>Guinea</item>
            <item>Guinea-Bissau</item>
            <item>Guyana</item>
            <item>Haiti</item>
            <item>Heard Island and McDonald Islands</item>
            <item>Honduras</item>
            <item>Hong Kong</item>
            <item>Hungary</item>
            <item>Iceland</item>
            <item>India</item>
            <item>Indonesia</item>
            <item>Iran</item>
            <item>Iraq</item>
            <item>Ireland</item>
            <item>Israel</item>
            <item>Italy</item>
            <item>Jamaica</item>
            <item>Japan</item>
            <item>Jordan</item>
            <item>Kazakhstan</item>
            <item>Kenya</item>
            <item>Kiribati</item>
            <item>Kuwait</item>
            <item>Kyrgyzstan</item>
            <item>Laos</item>
            <item>Latvia</item>
            <item>Lebanon</item>
            <item>Lesotho</item>
            <item>Liberia</item>
            <item>Libya</item>
            <item>Liechtenstein</item>
            <item>Lithuania</item>
            <item>Luxembourg</item>
            <item>Macau</item>
            <item>Madagascar</item>
            <item>Malawi</item>
            <item>Malaysia</item>
            <item>Maldives</item>
            <item>Mali</item>
            <item>Malta</item>
            <item>Marshall Islands</item>
            <item>Martinique</item>
            <item>Mauritania</item>
            <item>Mauritius</item>
            <item>Mayotte</item>
            <item>Mexico</item>
            <item>Micronesia</item>
            <item>Moldova</item>
            <item>Monaco</item>
            <item>Mongolia</item>
            <item>Montenegro</item>
            <item>Montserrat</item>
            <item>Morocco</item>
            <item>Mozambique</item>
            <item>Myanmar</item>
            <item>Namibia</item>
            <item>Nauru</item>
            <item>Nepal</item>
            <item>Netherlands</item>
            <item>Netherlands Antilles</item>
            <item>New Caledonia</item>
            <item>New Zealand</item>
            <item>Nicaragua</item>
            <item>Niger</item>
            <item>Nigeria</item>
            <item>Niue</item>
            <item>Norfolk Island</item>
            <item>North Korea</item>
            <item>Northern Marianas</item>
            <item>Norway</item>
            <item>Oman</item>
            <item>Pakistan</item>
            <item>Palau</item>
            <item>Panama</item>
            <item>Papua New Guinea</item>
            <item>Paraguay</item>
            <item>Peru</item>
            <item>Philippines</item>
            <item>Pitcairn Islands</item>
            <item>Poland</item>
            <item>Portugal</item>
            <item>Puerto Rico</item>
            <item>Qatar</item>
            <item>Reunion</item>
            <item>Romania</item>
            <item>Russia</item>
            <item>Rwanda</item>
            <item>Sqo Tome and Principe</item>
            <item>Saint Helena</item>
            <item>Saint Kitts and Nevis</item>
            <item>Saint Lucia</item>
            <item>Saint Pierre and Miquelon</item>
            <item>Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</item>
            <item>Samoa</item>
            <item>San Marino</item>
            <item>Saudi Arabia</item>
            <item>Senegal</item>
            <item>Serbia</item>
            <item>Seychelles</item>
            <item>Sierra Leone</item>
            <item>Singapore</item>
            <item>Slovakia</item>
            <item>Slovenia</item>
            <item>Solomon Islands</item>
            <item>Somalia</item>
            <item>South Africa</item>
            <item>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</item>
            <item>South Korea</item>
            <item>South Sudan</item>
            <item>Spain</item>
            <item>Sri Lanka</item>
            <item>Sudan</item>
            <item>Suriname</item>
            <item>Svalbard and Jan Mayen</item>
            <item>Swaziland</item>
            <item>Sweden</item>
            <item>Switzerland</item>
            <item>Syria</item>
            <item>Taiwan</item>
            <item>Tajikistan</item>
            <item>Tanzania</item>
            <item>Thailand</item>
            <item>The Bahamas</item>
            <item>The Gambia</item>
            <item>Togo</item>
            <item>Tokelau</item>
            <item>Tonga</item>
            <item>Trinidad and Tobago</item>
            <item>Tunisia</item>
            <item>Turkey</item>
            <item>Turkmenistan</item>
            <item>Turks and Caicos Islands</item>
            <item>Tuvalu</item>
            <item>Virgin Islands</item>
            <item>Uganda</item>
            <item>Ukraine</item>
            <item>United Arab Emirates</item>
            <item>United Kingdom</item>
            <item>United States</item>
            <item>United States Minor Outlying Islands</item>
            <item>Uruguay</item>
            <item>Uzbekistan</item>
            <item>Vanuatu</item>
            <item>Vatican City</item>
            <item>Venezuela</item>
            <item>Vietnam</item>
            <item>Wallis and Futuna</item>
            <item>Western Sahara</item>
            <item>Yemen</item>
            <item>Yugoslavia</item>
            <item>Zambia</item>
            <item>Zimbabwe</item>
        </string-array>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to use Google's [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) anyway, and if you work with phone numbers, it's rather likely you do, you can use its internal data that describes the same. It's not public, so you have to use reflection to reach it:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> CountryCodeToRegionCodeMap_getCountryCodeToRegionCodeMap() {
  try {
    Method method = CountryCodeToRegionCodeMap.class.getDeclaredMethod("getCountryCodeToRegionCodeMap");
    method.setAccessible(true);
    return (Map<Integer, List<String>>) method.invoke(null);
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(..., e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then you can search or process that map to get the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

I know it way too late. But I have a batter solution of it. Since doing it with the list of `String` and looping through it might slow it down. Using `Hashmap` would be a batter solution for it. 
I wrote a `PhoneUtil` class for it. Here is code ( i only have 20 or so countries but you can add more to it )

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Dell on 1/19/2017.
 */

public class PhoneUtil {
    public static String getCountryCode(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (manager != null) {
            return getCountryCodeFromMap(manager.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase());
        } else {
            return null;

        }

    }

    private static String getCountryCodeFromMap(String countryCode) {
        HashMap<String, String> countryCodeMap = new HashMap<>();

          countryCodeMap.put("TJ", "+992");
    countryCodeMap.put("TZ", "+255");
    countryCodeMap.put("TH", "+66");
    countryCodeMap.put("TG", "+228");
    countryCodeMap.put("TK", "+690");
    countryCodeMap.put("TO", "+676");
    countryCodeMap.put("TN", "+216");
    countryCodeMap.put("TR", "+90");
    countryCodeMap.put("TM", "+993");
    countryCodeMap.put("TV", "+688");
    countryCodeMap.put("AE", "+971");
    countryCodeMap.put("UG", "+256");
    countryCodeMap.put("GB", "+44");
    countryCodeMap.put("UA", "+380");
    countryCodeMap.put("UY", "+598");
    countryCodeMap.put("US", "+1");
    countryCodeMap.put("UZ", "+998");
    countryCodeMap.put("VU", "+678");
    countryCodeMap.put("VA", "+39");
    countryCodeMap.put("VE", "+58");
    countryCodeMap.put("VN", "+84");
    countryCodeMap.put("WF", "+681");
    countryCodeMap.put("YE", "+967");
    countryCodeMap.put("ZM", "+260");
    countryCodeMap.put("ZW", "+263");
    countryCodeMap.put( "MY","+60");
    countryCodeMap.put("PK","+92");
        return countryCodeMap.get(countryCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is going to fill (and then destroy) the hashmap at every lookup: unnecessary CPU and memory work. Hardcode for these codes might be fair enough. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32965373/214517

Answer (score 0):

In class TelephonyManager, I find a method `public String getNetworkCountryIso ()`, this may be what you want. Also, there are some other method which can return more info about the phone. You may read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_country_codes to see which country is represented by a MCC.

Answer (score -1):

This is code to put in your Main Activity to replace the code that Wais posted near the top of this page. Take the array that Wais posted and add that to your app in the resources. I might have slightly changed the name of the array to be stored in resources, other than that, this code should work well and be easier to read if you are learning:

```
public String getCountryCode()
{
    String my_country_code_letters = getMyLocale().getCountry();

    String[] country_codes = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_codes);

    String my_country_code_number = null;
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for (int i=0; i < country_codes.length && i != (-1); i++)
    {
        /**split_code:
         * 1) split_code[0] == numbers
         * 2) split_code[1] == letters**/
        String[] split_code = country_codes[i].split(",");
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (split_code[1].matches(my_country_code_letters))
        {
            my_country_code_number = split_code[0];
            break;
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return my_country_code_number;
}

public Locale getMyLocale()
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Running getMyLocale()");

    Locale myLocale = "";
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    {
        myLocale = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
    }
    else
    {
        //noinspection deprecation
        myLocale = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return myLocale;
}
```