# Android Get caller

Tags: java, android

I'm working for test app that shows Caller's name on the display of cell phone. 
How could I get a caller's name?
I wrote BroadcastReceiver that init my app when somebody calling, but how I can get WHO is calling?

Comment: Visit this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-country-code-with-android