# how to get country phone prefix from iso

Tags: java, android

I got the country iso by the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659809/where-am-i-get-country):

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCode = tm.getSimCountryIso();
```

how can I get the prefix phone number for country?
for example +972 for il.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found a place where I can get the mapping in csv file. [check here.](http://www.andrewpatton.com/countrylist.html)

Also, I changed it into a class that translate the country code into phone prefix. here it is:

```
public class Iso2Phone {
public static String getPhone(String code) {
    return country2phone.get(code.toUpperCase());
}
public static Map<String, String> getAll(){
    return country2phone;
}
private static Map<String, String> country2phone = new HashMap<String, String>();
static {
    country2phone.put("AF", "+93");
    country2phone.put("AL", "+355");
    country2phone.put("DZ", "+213");
    country2phone.put("AD", "+376");
    country2phone.put("AO", "+244");
    country2phone.put("AG", "+1-268");
    country2phone.put("AR", "+54");
    country2phone.put("AM", "+374");
    country2phone.put("AU", "+61");
    country2phone.put("AT", "+43");
    country2phone.put("AZ", "+994");
    country2phone.put("BS", "+1-242");
    country2phone.put("BH", "+973");
    country2phone.put("BD", "+880");
    country2phone.put("BB", "+1-246");
    country2phone.put("BY", "+375");
    country2phone.put("BE", "+32");
    country2phone.put("BZ", "+501");
    country2phone.put("BJ", "+229");
    country2phone.put("BT", "+975");
    country2phone.put("BO", "+591");
    country2phone.put("BA", "+387");
    country2phone.put("BW", "+267");
    country2phone.put("BR", "+55");
    country2phone.put("BN", "+673");
    country2phone.put("BG", "+359");
    country2phone.put("BF", "+226");
    country2phone.put("BI", "+257");
    country2phone.put("KH", "+855");
    country2phone.put("CM", "+237");
    country2phone.put("CA", "+1");
    country2phone.put("CV", "+238");
    country2phone.put("CF", "+236");
    country2phone.put("TD", "+235");
    country2phone.put("CL", "+56");
    country2phone.put("CN", "+86");
    country2phone.put("CO", "+57");
    country2phone.put("KM", "+269");
    country2phone.put("CD", "+243");
    country2phone.put("CG", "+242");
    country2phone.put("CR", "+506");
    country2phone.put("CI", "+225");
    country2phone.put("HR", "+385");
    country2phone.put("CU", "+53");
    country2phone.put("CY", "+357");
    country2phone.put("CZ", "+420");
    country2phone.put("DK", "+45");
    country2phone.put("DJ", "+253");
    country2phone.put("DM", "+1-767");
    country2phone.put("DO", "+1-809and1-829");
    country2phone.put("EC", "+593");
    country2phone.put("EG", "+20");
    country2phone.put("SV", "+503");
    country2phone.put("GQ", "+240");
    country2phone.put("ER", "+291");
    country2phone.put("EE", "+372");
    country2phone.put("ET", "+251");
    country2phone.put("FJ", "+679");
    country2phone.put("FI", "+358");
    country2phone.put("FR", "+33");
    country2phone.put("GA", "+241");
    country2phone.put("GM", "+220");
    country2phone.put("GE", "+995");
    country2phone.put("DE", "+49");
    country2phone.put("GH", "+233");
    country2phone.put("GR", "+30");
    country2phone.put("GD", "+1-473");
    country2phone.put("GT", "+502");
    country2phone.put("GN", "+224");
    country2phone.put("GW", "+245");
    country2phone.put("GY", "+592");
    country2phone.put("HT", "+509");
    country2phone.put("HN", "+504");
    country2phone.put("HU", "+36");
    country2phone.put("IS", "+354");
    country2phone.put("IN", "+91");
    country2phone.put("ID", "+62");
    country2phone.put("IR", "+98");
    country2phone.put("IQ", "+964");
    country2phone.put("IE", "+353");
    country2phone.put("IL", "+972");
    country2phone.put("IT", "+39");
    country2phone.put("JM", "+1-876");
    country2phone.put("JP", "+81");
    country2phone.put("JO", "+962");
    country2phone.put("KZ", "+7");
    country2phone.put("KE", "+254");
    country2phone.put("KI", "+686");
    country2phone.put("KP", "+850");
    country2phone.put("KR", "+82");
    country2phone.put("KW", "+965");
    country2phone.put("KG", "+996");
    country2phone.put("LA", "+856");
    country2phone.put("LV", "+371");
    country2phone.put("LB", "+961");
    country2phone.put("LS", "+266");
    country2phone.put("LR", "+231");
    country2phone.put("LY", "+218");
    country2phone.put("LI", "+423");
    country2phone.put("LT", "+370");
    country2phone.put("LU", "+352");
    country2phone.put("MK", "+389");
    country2phone.put("MG", "+261");
    country2phone.put("MW", "+265");
    country2phone.put("MY", "+60");
    country2phone.put("MV", "+960");
    country2phone.put("ML", "+223");
    country2phone.put("MT", "+356");
    country2phone.put("MH", "+692");
    country2phone.put("MR", "+222");
    country2phone.put("MU", "+230");
    country2phone.put("MX", "+52");
    country2phone.put("FM", "+691");
    country2phone.put("MD", "+373");
    country2phone.put("MC", "+377");
    country2phone.put("MN", "+976");
    country2phone.put("ME", "+382");
    country2phone.put("MA", "+212");
    country2phone.put("MZ", "+258");
    country2phone.put("MM", "+95");
    country2phone.put("NA", "+264");
    country2phone.put("NR", "+674");
    country2phone.put("NP", "+977");
    country2phone.put("NL", "+31");
    country2phone.put("NZ", "+64");
    country2phone.put("NI", "+505");
    country2phone.put("NE", "+227");
    country2phone.put("NG", "+234");
    country2phone.put("NO", "+47");
    country2phone.put("OM", "+968");
    country2phone.put("PK", "+92");
    country2phone.put("PW", "+680");
    country2phone.put("PA", "+507");
    country2phone.put("PG", "+675");
    country2phone.put("PY", "+595");
    country2phone.put("PE", "+51");
    country2phone.put("PH", "+63");
    country2phone.put("PL", "+48");
    country2phone.put("PT", "+351");
    country2phone.put("QA", "+974");
    country2phone.put("RO", "+40");
    country2phone.put("RU", "+7");
    country2phone.put("RW", "+250");
    country2phone.put("KN", "+1-869");
    country2phone.put("LC", "+1-758");
    country2phone.put("VC", "+1-784");
    country2phone.put("WS", "+685");
    country2phone.put("SM", "+378");
    country2phone.put("ST", "+239");
    country2phone.put("SA", "+966");
    country2phone.put("SN", "+221");
    country2phone.put("RS", "+381");
    country2phone.put("SC", "+248");
    country2phone.put("SL", "+232");
    country2phone.put("SG", "+65");
    country2phone.put("SK", "+421");
    country2phone.put("SI", "+386");
    country2phone.put("SB", "+677");
    country2phone.put("SO", "+252");
    country2phone.put("ZA", "+27");
    country2phone.put("ES", "+34");
    country2phone.put("LK", "+94");
    country2phone.put("SD", "+249");
    country2phone.put("SR", "+597");
    country2phone.put("SZ", "+268");
    country2phone.put("SE", "+46");
    country2phone.put("CH", "+41");
    country2phone.put("SY", "+963");
    country2phone.put("TJ", "+992");
    country2phone.put("TZ", "+255");
    country2phone.put("TH", "+66");
    country2phone.put("TL", "+670");
    country2phone.put("TG", "+228");
    country2phone.put("TO", "+676");
    country2phone.put("TT", "+1-868");
    country2phone.put("TN", "+216");
    country2phone.put("TR", "+90");
    country2phone.put("TM", "+993");
    country2phone.put("TV", "+688");
    country2phone.put("UG", "+256");
    country2phone.put("UA", "+380");
    country2phone.put("AE", "+971");
    country2phone.put("GB", "+44");
    country2phone.put("US", "+1");
    country2phone.put("UY", "+598");
    country2phone.put("UZ", "+998");
    country2phone.put("VU", "+678");
    country2phone.put("VA", "+379");
    country2phone.put("VE", "+58");
    country2phone.put("VN", "+84");
    country2phone.put("YE", "+967");
    country2phone.put("ZM", "+260");
    country2phone.put("ZW", "+263");
    country2phone.put("GE", "+995");
    country2phone.put("TW", "+886");
    country2phone.put("AZ", "+374-97");
    country2phone.put("CY", "+90-392");
    country2phone.put("MD", "+373-533");
    country2phone.put("SO", "+252");
    country2phone.put("GE", "+995");
    country2phone.put("CX", "+61");
    country2phone.put("CC", "+61");
    country2phone.put("NF", "+672");
    country2phone.put("NC", "+687");
    country2phone.put("PF", "+689");
    country2phone.put("YT", "+262");
    country2phone.put("GP", "+590");
    country2phone.put("GP", "+590");
    country2phone.put("PM", "+508");
    country2phone.put("WF", "+681");
    country2phone.put("CK", "+682");
    country2phone.put("NU", "+683");
    country2phone.put("TK", "+690");
    country2phone.put("GG", "+44");
    country2phone.put("IM", "+44");
    country2phone.put("JE", "+44");
    country2phone.put("AI", "+1-264");
    country2phone.put("BM", "+1-441");
    country2phone.put("IO", "+246");
    country2phone.put("", "+357");
    country2phone.put("VG", "+1-284");
    country2phone.put("KY", "+1-345");
    country2phone.put("FK", "+500");
    country2phone.put("GI", "+350");
    country2phone.put("MS", "+1-664");
    country2phone.put("SH", "+290");
    country2phone.put("TC", "+1-649");
    country2phone.put("MP", "+1-670");
    country2phone.put("PR", "+1-787and1-939");
    country2phone.put("AS", "+1-684");
    country2phone.put("GU", "+1-671");
    country2phone.put("VI", "+1-340");
    country2phone.put("HK", "+852");
    country2phone.put("MO", "+853");
    country2phone.put("FO", "+298");
    country2phone.put("GL", "+299");
    country2phone.put("GF", "+594");
    country2phone.put("GP", "+590");
    country2phone.put("MQ", "+596");
    country2phone.put("RE", "+262");
    country2phone.put("AX", "+358-18");
    country2phone.put("AW", "+297");
    country2phone.put("AN", "+599");
    country2phone.put("SJ", "+47");
    country2phone.put("AC", "+247");
    country2phone.put("TA", "+290");
    country2phone.put("CS", "+381");
    country2phone.put("PS", "+970");
    country2phone.put("EH", "+212");
}
}
```

Comment: Could do with a bit of work - lots of repeated empty entries for "AQ", "AU" is set and then unset...

Comment: @Abhi - I wrote it myself.

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor - Thanks, I think I fixed those entries now.

Comment: better change this line:
   `country2phone.put("", "+357");`

Comment: Is this line all right? `country2phone.put("DO", "+1-809and1-829");` There are a couple other similar ones that might need fixing, too.

Answer (score 35):

You could use the library called [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) available on Github, made by Google developers. For example you can get the prefix using:

```
PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().getCountryCodeForRegion("DE");
```

It also has a lot of useful functions to parse phone numbers.

Answer (score 13):

Tidying up @oshai's answer

```
public class CountryToPhonePrefix {

private static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

public String prefixFor(String iso2CountryCode) {
    String result = map.get(iso2CountryCode);
    if (result == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown country code " + iso2CountryCode);
    }
    return result;
}

static {
    map.put("AC", "+247");
    map.put("AD", "+376");
    map.put("AE", "+971");
    map.put("AF", "+93");
    map.put("AG", "+1-268");
    map.put("AI", "+1-264");
    map.put("AL", "+355");
    map.put("AM", "+374");
    map.put("AN", "+599");
    map.put("AO", "+244");
    map.put("AR", "+54");
    map.put("AS", "+1-684");
    map.put("AT", "+43");
    map.put("AU", "+61");
    map.put("AW", "+297");
    map.put("AX", "+358-18");
    map.put("AZ", "+374-97");
    map.put("AZ", "+994");
    map.put("BA", "+387");
    map.put("BB", "+1-246");
    map.put("BD", "+880");
    map.put("BE", "+32");
    map.put("BF", "+226");
    map.put("BG", "+359");
    map.put("BH", "+973");
    map.put("BI", "+257");
    map.put("BJ", "+229");
    map.put("BM", "+1-441");
    map.put("BN", "+673");
    map.put("BO", "+591");
    map.put("BR", "+55");
    map.put("BS", "+1-242");
    map.put("BT", "+975");
    map.put("BW", "+267");
    map.put("BY", "+375");
    map.put("BZ", "+501");
    map.put("CA", "+1");
    map.put("CC", "+61");
    map.put("CD", "+243");
    map.put("CF", "+236");
    map.put("CG", "+242");
    map.put("CH", "+41");
    map.put("CI", "+225");
    map.put("CK", "+682");
    map.put("CL", "+56");
    map.put("CM", "+237");
    map.put("CN", "+86");
    map.put("CO", "+57");
    map.put("CR", "+506");
    map.put("CS", "+381");
    map.put("CU", "+53");
    map.put("CV", "+238");
    map.put("CX", "+61");
    map.put("CY", "+90-392");
    map.put("CY", "+357");
    map.put("CZ", "+420");
    map.put("DE", "+49");
    map.put("DJ", "+253");
    map.put("DK", "+45");
    map.put("DM", "+1-767");
    map.put("DO", "+1-809"); // and 1-829?
    map.put("DZ", "+213");
    map.put("EC", "+593");
    map.put("EE", "+372");
    map.put("EG", "+20");
    map.put("EH", "+212");
    map.put("ER", "+291");
    map.put("ES", "+34");
    map.put("ET", "+251");
    map.put("FI", "+358");
    map.put("FJ", "+679");
    map.put("FK", "+500");
    map.put("FM", "+691");
    map.put("FO", "+298");
    map.put("FR", "+33");
    map.put("GA", "+241");
    map.put("GB", "+44");
    map.put("GD", "+1-473");
    map.put("GE", "+995");
    map.put("GF", "+594");
    map.put("GG", "+44");
    map.put("GH", "+233");
    map.put("GI", "+350");
    map.put("GL", "+299");
    map.put("GM", "+220");
    map.put("GN", "+224");
    map.put("GP", "+590");
    map.put("GQ", "+240");
    map.put("GR", "+30");
    map.put("GT", "+502");
    map.put("GU", "+1-671");
    map.put("GW", "+245");
    map.put("GY", "+592");
    map.put("HK", "+852");
    map.put("HN", "+504");
    map.put("HR", "+385");
    map.put("HT", "+509");
    map.put("HU", "+36");
    map.put("ID", "+62");
    map.put("IE", "+353");
    map.put("IL", "+972");
    map.put("IM", "+44");
    map.put("IN", "+91");
    map.put("IO", "+246");
    map.put("IQ", "+964");
    map.put("IR", "+98");
    map.put("IS", "+354");
    map.put("IT", "+39");
    map.put("JE", "+44");
    map.put("JM", "+1-876");
    map.put("JO", "+962");
    map.put("JP", "+81");
    map.put("KE", "+254");
    map.put("KG", "+996");
    map.put("KH", "+855");
    map.put("KI", "+686");
    map.put("KM", "+269");
    map.put("KN", "+1-869");
    map.put("KP", "+850");
    map.put("KR", "+82");
    map.put("KW", "+965");
    map.put("KY", "+1-345");
    map.put("KZ", "+7");
    map.put("LA", "+856");
    map.put("LB", "+961");
    map.put("LC", "+1-758");
    map.put("LI", "+423");
    map.put("LK", "+94");
    map.put("LR", "+231");
    map.put("LS", "+266");
    map.put("LT", "+370");
    map.put("LU", "+352");
    map.put("LV", "+371");
    map.put("LY", "+218");
    map.put("MA", "+212");
    map.put("MC", "+377");
    map.put("MD", "+373-533");
    map.put("MD", "+373");
    map.put("ME", "+382");
    map.put("MG", "+261");
    map.put("MH", "+692");
    map.put("MK", "+389");
    map.put("ML", "+223");
    map.put("MM", "+95");
    map.put("MN", "+976");
    map.put("MO", "+853");
    map.put("MP", "+1-670");
    map.put("MQ", "+596");
    map.put("MR", "+222");
    map.put("MS", "+1-664");
    map.put("MT", "+356");
    map.put("MU", "+230");
    map.put("MV", "+960");
    map.put("MW", "+265");
    map.put("MX", "+52");
    map.put("MY", "+60");
    map.put("MZ", "+258");
    map.put("NA", "+264");
    map.put("NC", "+687");
    map.put("NE", "+227");
    map.put("NF", "+672");
    map.put("NG", "+234");
    map.put("NI", "+505");
    map.put("NL", "+31");
    map.put("NO", "+47");
    map.put("NP", "+977");
    map.put("NR", "+674");
    map.put("NU", "+683");
    map.put("NZ", "+64");
    map.put("OM", "+968");
    map.put("PA", "+507");
    map.put("PE", "+51");
    map.put("PF", "+689");
    map.put("PG", "+675");
    map.put("PH", "+63");
    map.put("PK", "+92");
    map.put("PL", "+48");
    map.put("PM", "+508");
    map.put("PR", "+1-787"); // and 1-939 ?
    map.put("PS", "+970");
    map.put("PT", "+351");
    map.put("PW", "+680");
    map.put("PY", "+595");
    map.put("QA", "+974");
    map.put("RE", "+262");
    map.put("RO", "+40");
    map.put("RS", "+381");
    map.put("RU", "+7");
    map.put("RW", "+250");
    map.put("SA", "+966");
    map.put("SB", "+677");
    map.put("SC", "+248");
    map.put("SD", "+249");
    map.put("SE", "+46");
    map.put("SG", "+65");
    map.put("SH", "+290");
    map.put("SI", "+386");
    map.put("SJ", "+47");
    map.put("SK", "+421");
    map.put("SL", "+232");
    map.put("SM", "+378");
    map.put("SN", "+221");
    map.put("SO", "+252");
    map.put("SO", "+252");
    map.put("SR", "+597");
    map.put("ST", "+239");
    map.put("SV", "+503");
    map.put("SY", "+963");
    map.put("SZ", "+268");
    map.put("TA", "+290");
    map.put("TC", "+1-649");
    map.put("TD", "+235");
    map.put("TG", "+228");
    map.put("TH", "+66");
    map.put("TJ", "+992");
    map.put("TK", "+690");
    map.put("TL", "+670");
    map.put("TM", "+993");
    map.put("TN", "+216");
    map.put("TO", "+676");
    map.put("TR", "+90");
    map.put("TT", "+1-868");
    map.put("TV", "+688");
    map.put("TW", "+886");
    map.put("TZ", "+255");
    map.put("UA", "+380");
    map.put("UG", "+256");
    map.put("US", "+1");
    map.put("UY", "+598");
    map.put("UZ", "+998");
    map.put("VA", "+379");
    map.put("VC", "+1-784");
    map.put("VE", "+58");
    map.put("VG", "+1-284");
    map.put("VI", "+1-340");
    map.put("VN", "+84");
    map.put("VU", "+678");
    map.put("WF", "+681");
    map.put("WS", "+685");
    map.put("YE", "+967");
    map.put("YT", "+262");
    map.put("ZA", "+27");
    map.put("ZM", "+260");
    map.put("ZW", "+263");
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-country-code-with-android)

```
 /**
     * network iso code: referred and listed at:
     * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_country_codes
     */
      TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String DEVICE_COUNTRY = manager.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

Update:: Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659809/where-am-i-get-country)

```
String locale = getApplicationCOntext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified @oshai answer in Kotlin and added a few missing countries:

```
class CountryToPhonePrefix {

fun prefixFor(iso2CountryCode: String): String {
    return prefixMap[iso2CountryCode]
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown country code $iso2CountryCode")
}

private val prefixMap: Map<String, String> = mapOf(
    "AC" to "+247",
    "AD" to "+376",
    "AE" to "+971",
    "AF" to "+93",
    "AG" to "+1-268",
    "AI" to "+1-264",
    "AL" to "+355",
    "AM" to "+374",
    "AN" to "+599",
    "AO" to "+244",
    "AQ" to "+672",
    "AR" to "+54",
    "AS" to "+1-684",
    "AT" to "+43",
    "AU" to "+61",
    "AW" to "+297",
    "AX" to "+358-18",
    "AZ" to "+374-97",
    "BA" to "+387",
    "BB" to "+1-246",
    "BD" to "+880",
    "BE" to "+32",
    "BF" to "+226",
    "BG" to "+359",
    "BH" to "+973",
    "BI" to "+257",
    "BJ" to "+229",
    "BM" to "+1-441",
    "BN" to "+673",
    "BL" to "+590",
    "BO" to "+591",
    "BQ" to "+599",
    "BR" to "+55",
    "BS" to "+1-242",
    "BT" to "+975",
    "BW" to "+267",
    "BV" to "+47",
    "BY" to "+375",
    "BZ" to "+501",
    "CA" to "+1",
    "CC" to "+61",
    "CD" to "+243",
    "CF" to "+236",
    "CG" to "+242",
    "CH" to "+41",
    "CI" to "+225",
    "CK" to "+682",
    "CL" to "+56",
    "CM" to "+237",
    "CN" to "+86",
    "CO" to "+57",
    "CR" to "+506",
    "CS" to "+381",
    "CU" to "+53",
    "CV" to "+238",
    "CW" to "+599",
    "CX" to "+61",
    "CY" to "+90-392",
    "CZ" to "+420",
    "DE" to "+49",
    "DJ" to "+253",
    "DK" to "+45",
    "DM" to "+1-767",
    "DO" to "+1-809",
    "DZ" to "+213",
    "EC" to "+593",
    "EE" to "+372",
    "EG" to "+20",
    "EH" to "+212",
    "ER" to "+291",
    "ES" to "+34",
    "ET" to "+251",
    "FI" to "+358",
    "FJ" to "+679",
    "FK" to "+500",
    "FM" to "+691",
    "FO" to "+298",
    "FR" to "+33",
    "GA" to "+241",
    "GB" to "+44",
    "GD" to "+1-473",
    "GE" to "+995",
    "GF" to "+594",
    "GG" to "+44",
    "GH" to "+233",
    "GI" to "+350",
    "GL" to "+299",
    "GM" to "+220",
    "GN" to "+224",
    "GP" to "+590",
    "GQ" to "+240",
    "GR" to "+30",
    "GS" to "+500",
    "GT" to "+502",
    "GU" to "+1-671",
    "GW" to "+245",
    "GY" to "+592",
    "HK" to "+852",
    "HN" to "+504",
    "HR" to "+385",
    "HT" to "+509",
    "HU" to "+36",
    "ID" to "+62",
    "IE" to "+353",
    "IL" to "+972",
    "IM" to "+44",
    "IN" to "+91",
    "IO" to "+246",
    "IQ" to "+964",
    "IR" to "+98",
    "IS" to "+354",
    "IT" to "+39",
    "JE" to "+44",
    "JM" to "+1-876",
    "JO" to "+962",
    "JP" to "+81",
    "KE" to "+254",
    "KG" to "+996",
    "KH" to "+855",
    "KI" to "+686",
    "KM" to "+269",
    "KN" to "+1-869",
    "KP" to "+850",
    "KR" to "+82",
    "KW" to "+965",
    "KY" to "+1-345",
    "KZ" to "+7",
    "LA" to "+856",
    "LB" to "+961",
    "LC" to "+1-758",
    "LI" to "+423",
    "LK" to "+94",
    "LR" to "+231",
    "LS" to "+266",
    "LT" to "+370",
    "LU" to "+352",
    "LV" to "+371",
    "LY" to "+218",
    "MA" to "+212",
    "MC" to "+377",
    "MD" to "+373-533",
    "ME" to "+382",
    "MF" to "+590",
    "MG" to "+261",
    "MH" to "+692",
    "MK" to "+389",
    "ML" to "+223",
    "MM" to "+95",
    "MN" to "+976",
    "MO" to "+853",
    "MP" to "+1-670",
    "MQ" to "+596",
    "MR" to "+222",
    "MS" to "+1-664",
    "MT" to "+356",
    "MU" to "+230",
    "MV" to "+960",
    "MW" to "+265",
    "MX" to "+52",
    "MY" to "+60",
    "MZ" to "+258",
    "NA" to "+264",
    "NC" to "+687",
    "NE" to "+227",
    "NF" to "+672",
    "NG" to "+234",
    "NI" to "+505",
    "NL" to "+31",
    "NO" to "+47",
    "NP" to "+977",
    "NR" to "+674",
    "NU" to "+683",
    "NZ" to "+64",
    "OM" to "+968",
    "PA" to "+507",
    "PE" to "+51",
    "PF" to "+689",
    "PG" to "+675",
    "PH" to "+63",
    "PK" to "+92",
    "PL" to "+48",
    "PM" to "+508",
    "PR" to "+1-787",
    "PS" to "+970",
    "PT" to "+351",
    "PW" to "+680",
    "PY" to "+595",
    "QA" to "+974",
    "RE" to "+262",
    "RO" to "+40",
    "RS" to "+381",
    "RU" to "+7",
    "RW" to "+250",
    "SA" to "+966",
    "SB" to "+677",
    "SC" to "+248",
    "SD" to "+249",
    "SE" to "+46",
    "SG" to "+65",
    "SH" to "+290",
    "SI" to "+386",
    "SJ" to "+47",
    "SK" to "+421",
    "SL" to "+232",
    "SM" to "+378",
    "SN" to "+221",
    "SO" to "+252",
    "SR" to "+597",
    "SS" to "+211",
    "ST" to "+239",
    "SV" to "+503",
    "SX" to "+721",
    "SY" to "+963",
    "SZ" to "+268",
    "TA" to "+290",
    "TC" to "+1-649",
    "TD" to "+235",
    "TG" to "+228",
    "TH" to "+66",
    "TJ" to "+992",
    "TK" to "+690",
    "TL" to "+670",
    "TM" to "+993",
    "TN" to "+216",
    "TO" to "+676",
    "TR" to "+90",
    "TT" to "+1-868",
    "TV" to "+688",
    "TW" to "+886",
    "TZ" to "+255",
    "UA" to "+380",
    "UG" to "+256",
    "US" to "+1",
    "UY" to "+598",
    "UZ" to "+998",
    "VA" to "+379",
    "VC" to "+1-784",
    "VE" to "+58",
    "VG" to "+1-284",
    "VI" to "+1-340",
    "VN" to "+84",
    "VU" to "+678",
    "WF" to "+681",
    "WS" to "+685",
    "YE" to "+967",
    "YT" to "+262",
    "ZA" to "+27",
    "ZM" to "+260",
    "ZW" to "+263"
)
```

}