# Java lib for suggesting international phone prefix by country

Tags: java

Is there any java library which helps suggest international phone prefix by country?
For example, We have Romania and the suggestion would be +40

Comment: Not Sure, but why not have it in a Map? One time effort

Comment: Agree with rajesh: get your list (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes#Complete_listing) and store it in a `Map`

Comment: it's a lot:) but thanks

Comment: You can copy paste the wiki link content @Heuster posted to a text file. Parse it and populate the map

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772329/how-to-get-country-phone-prefix-from-iso

Comment: You can try using Google's phone number library http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Comment: @rajesh - Not a one time effort.  The effort needs to be repeated each time there is a change.  A better approach is suggested by the linked question.