# How to get country code in Android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

How to get country code like **+91** for India  and **+1** for US.

This is my code,

```
 TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 String CountryID= manager.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();
```

Above code shows IN. Please help me.

Comment: `IN` is the ISO country code for india

Comment: Its better to ask from user

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be helpful.

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the prefix automatically from the sdk.

I had a similar problem and I solved by creating pre-populated json and reading it (but is not the best way)

I suggest you to read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10776064/3608785) with a quickly and efficient solution.