# Find Country code by using Mobile Number Android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Is there any way to find the country code from my mobile number. Basically, I am working for a chat application I need to find the country code by using the mobile number. Is it possible?

For example:

```
My Country - India,
Country Code - +91,
My number - 9787248566
```

Now I have only my number . I don't know the country code. I don't know which country it is. Is it possible to achieve this in Android programmatically?

Comment: with country name your find the county code..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-country-code-with-android

Comment: Please read the question I mentioned this.  "I don't know which country it is"

Comment: "I don't know the country code. I don't know which country it is." - Then you can't know for certain. Searching for just that number gives me a location in Worcester, Massachusetts, USA, which clearly isn't what you want.

Comment: Yes exactly if I use this number then it will show different country.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have complete mobile number in a specific format e.g. **+91-99xxxxxxxx** and want to fetch country code = **IN**, then here is a reference to a solution.

Use a lib in your gradle.

```
//Phone Utils lib.
implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0'
```

And the code which will help to find the country code and other information is as below.

```
PhoneNumberUtil utils = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
    for (String region : utils.getSupportedRegions()) {
        // Check whether it's a valid number.
        boolean isValid = utils.isPossibleNumber(mobileNo, region);
        if (isValid) {
            Phonenumber.PhoneNumber number = util.parse(mobileNo, region);
            // Check whether it's a valid number for the given region.
            isValid = utils.isValidNumberForRegion(number, region);
            if (isValid) {
                Log.d("Region:" , region); // IN
                Log.d("Phone Code", number.getCountryCode()); // 91
                Log.d("Phone No.", number.getNationalNumber()); // 99xxxxxxxxxx  
            }
        }
    }
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What if we get multiple country code support for same number inside loop how we can handle it here with this code ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`TelephonyManager.getSimCountryIso()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimCountryIso()).

If you want to map that to the number, see [how to get country phone prefix from iso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772329/how-to-get-country-phone-prefix-from-iso)