# Is there a means in android for looking up telephony country code

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I am building an app that makes use of phone numbers. I would like to have a user select a country and then based on that country prepend the country code to their phone number. 
Is there a standard way for doing this in android? I thought the answer was [Place AutoComplete](https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android), an android service for adding places, but that does not seem to be the answer; at least I can't get the country code from that service as explained on The Google Developer Academy site.

Does anyone know how I might get this done?

Comment: edited to remove hold

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-country-code-with-android?lq=1

Comment: That link is not completely bad, but it is lacking a lot. I need full country name(s) not just abbreviations. So perhaps I can hardcode this myself, but oh boy the possibility for error is so great. As for using the network country (`manager.getNetworkCountryIso()`), the device may not be a phone. So imagine user using a tablet/pad but owns a valid phone number on another device. User may be using pad in US while phone number is for Haiti or France or who knows? I will rack my brain against the answer in that link, but please, if someone has already solved this problem: help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) library by google for handling phone numbers on android. You will need to send the country code once the user selects and then use the PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().parse(,)