# how to get country ISD code when User Select Country name from Spinner

Tags: android

```
package com.example.imageslideshow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class RegitsraionPage extends Activity {

    private Spinner country;
    EditText editext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.registraion);
        country = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        editext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Locale locale : locales) {
            String country = locale.getDisplayCountry();
            if (country.trim().length() > 0 && !countries.contains(country)) {
                countries.add(country);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(countries);
        for (String country : countries) {
            System.out.println(country);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinner_item, countries);
        // set the view for the Drop down list
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // set the ArrayAdapter to the spinner
        country.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
```

This is my code, using locale am able to display a country name in a Spinner. I am trying to code on EditText Box when I select a country to automaticly set ISD code to In EditTextbox please help me with how I can do this. If we select INDIA from drop down it should automaticly set +91 in edit text box.

Comment: Check this answer you may understand what you can do with your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-country-code-with-android

Comment: yes i did same But i aam unable to set Value on textview ISD Code when i select COuntry COde this example i followed But i unabale to set value when i select country name .plz help

Comment: @AHegde please help how i will compare country name with ISd code

Comment: Check which country you have selected out of the list of items in the array and accordingly display the country code

Comment: But i need to display ISD CODE not COUNTRY CODE like if we select India then it should display India ISD code 91

Comment: It is the telephone country code itself ,<item>91,IN</item>

Comment: yes Plz tell how i will set if we select CountryName http://snag.gy/CPDZJ.jpg like this

Comment: @AHegde any Solution for this U have ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this array to strings.xml

```
<string-array name="CountryCodes" >
<item>93,AF</item>
<item>355,AL</item>
<item>213,DZ</item>
<item>376,AD</item>
<item>244,AO</item>
<item>672,AQ</item>
<item>54,AR</item>
<item>374,AM</item>
<item>297,AW</item>
<item>61,AU</item>
<item>43,AT</item>
<item>994,AZ</item>
<item>973,BH</item>
<item>880,BD</item>
<item>375,BY</item>
<item>32,BE</item>
<item>501,BZ</item>
<item>229,BJ</item>
<item>975,BT</item>
<item>591,BO</item>
<item>387,BA</item>
<item>267,BW</item>
<item>55,BR</item>
<item>673,BN</item>
<item>359,BG</item>
<item>226,BF</item>
<item>95,MM</item>
<item>257,BI</item>
<item>855,KH</item>
<item>237,CM</item>
<item>1,CA</item>
<item>238,CV</item>
<item>236,CF</item>
<item>235,TD</item>
<item>56,CL</item>
<item>86,CN</item>
<item>61,CX</item>
<item>61,CC</item>
<item>57,CO</item>
<item>269,KM</item>
<item>242,CG</item>
<item>243,CD</item>
<item>682,CK</item>
<item>506,CR</item>
<item>385,HR</item>
<item>53,CU</item>
<item>357,CY</item>
<item>420,CZ</item>
<item>45,DK</item>
<item>253,DJ</item>
<item>670,TL</item>
<item>593,EC</item>
<item>20,EG</item>
<item>503,SV</item>
<item>240,GQ</item>
<item>291,ER</item>
<item>372,EE</item>
<item>251,ET</item>
<item>500,FK</item>
<item>298,FO</item>
<item>679,FJ</item>
<item>358,FI</item>
<item>33,FR</item>
<item>689,PF</item>
<item>241,GA</item>
<item>220,GM</item>
<item>995,GE</item>
<item>49,DE</item>
<item>233,GH</item>
<item>350,GI</item>
<item>30,GR</item>
<item>299,GL</item>
<item>502,GT</item>
<item>224,GN</item>
<item>245,GW</item>
<item>592,GY</item>
<item>509,HT</item>
<item>504,HN</item>
<item>852,HK</item>
<item>36,HU</item>
<item>91,IN</item>
<item>62,ID</item>
<item>98,IR</item>
<item>964,IQ</item>
<item>353,IE</item>
<item>44,IM</item>
<item>972,IL</item>
<item>39,IT</item>
<item>225,CI</item>
<item>81,JP</item>
<item>962,JO</item>
<item>7,KZ</item>
<item>254,KE</item>
<item>686,KI</item>
<item>965,KW</item>
<item>996,KG</item>
<item>856,LA</item>
<item>371,LV</item>
<item>961,LB</item>
<item>266,LS</item>
<item>231,LR</item>
<item>218,LY</item>
<item>423,LI</item>
<item>370,LT</item>
<item>352,LU</item>
<item>853,MO</item>
<item>389,MK</item>
<item>261,MG</item>
<item>265,MW</item>
<item>60,MY</item>
<item>960,MV</item>
<item>223,ML</item>
<item>356,MT</item>
<item>692,MH</item>
<item>222,MR</item>
<item>230,MU</item>
<item>262,YT</item>
<item>52,MX</item>
<item>691,FM</item>
<item>373,MD</item>
<item>377,MC</item>
<item>976,MN</item>
<item>382,ME</item>
<item>212,MA</item>
<item>258,MZ</item>
<item>264,NA</item>
<item>674,NR</item>
<item>977,NP</item>
<item>31,NL</item>
<item>599,AN</item>
<item>687,NC</item>
<item>64,NZ</item>
<item>505,NI</item>
<item>227,NE</item>
<item>234,NG</item>
<item>683,NU</item>
<item>850,KP</item>
<item>47,NO</item>
<item>968,OM</item>
<item>92,PK</item>
<item>680,PW</item>
<item>507,PA</item>
<item>675,PG</item>
<item>595,PY</item>
<item>51,PE</item>
<item>63,PH</item>
<item>870,PN</item>
<item>48,PL</item>
<item>351,PT</item>
<item>1,PR</item>
<item>974,QA</item>
<item>40,RO</item>
<item>7,RU</item>
<item>250,RW</item>
<item>590,BL</item>
<item>685,WS</item>
<item>378,SM</item>
<item>239,ST</item>
<item>966,SA</item>
<item>221,SN</item>
<item>381,RS</item>
<item>248,SC</item>
<item>232,SL</item>
<item>65,SG</item>
<item>421,SK</item>
<item>386,SI</item>
<item>677,SB</item>
<item>252,SO</item>
<item>27,ZA</item>
<item>82,KR</item>
<item>34,ES</item>
<item>94,LK</item>
<item>290,SH</item>
<item>508,PM</item>
<item>249,SD</item>
<item>597,SR</item>
<item>268,SZ</item>
<item>46,SE</item>
<item>41,CH</item>
<item>963,SY</item>
<item>886,TW</item>
<item>992,TJ</item>
<item>255,TZ</item>
<item>66,TH</item>
<item>228,TG</item>
<item>690,TK</item>
<item>676,TO</item>
<item>216,TN</item>
<item>90,TR</item>
<item>993,TM</item>
<item>688,TV</item>
<item>971,AE</item>
<item>256,UG</item>
<item>44,GB</item>
<item>380,UA</item>
<item>598,UY</item>
<item>1,US</item>
<item>998,UZ</item>
<item>678,VU</item>
<item>39,VA</item>
<item>58,VE</item>
<item>84,VN</item>
<item>681,WF</item>
<item>967,YE</item>
<item>260,ZM</item>
<item>263,ZW</item>
</string-array>
```

If you want full name of countries instead of ISO country codes like Zm,IN etc then you can replace it else keep it as it is.
Then Copy this Function To your Class,

```
String GetCountryZipCode(){

        String CountryID="";
        String CountryZipCode="";

       TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
              //getNetworkCountryIso
        CountryID= manager.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();
        String[] rl=this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryCodes);
        for(int i=0;i<rl.length;i++){
                                    String[] g=rl[i].split(",");
                                    if(g[1].trim().equals(CountryID.trim())){
                                                        CountryZipCode=g[0];break;  }
        }
```

Compare the 2 arrays i.e array of country names and country codes to get the required answer you want.

Comment: country.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
     long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
  });  i have to display In this

Comment: hello Any one please hlep

Comment: Yes you have to do it in ,country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {..});

Comment: But am not getting /2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/SMS/Messagesalue when i slect Country i mean i am not getting ISD CODE when I slect plz check and tell me that funcation