# How to get Country Name and Country Calling (ISD) Codes in a Spinner

Tags: java, android

In my android application. I have an registration page, where user have to enter his/her mobile no.

I want to display an spinner on left side of mobile no textview. when click on spinner is show a list of (country name, country calling code(ISD no). after selection on particular row country code should be reflect in mobile no. textview and after that Mobile No should be entered.

As there in [Gmail Registration Page](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&hl=en).

Comment: check this link,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291199/how-to-get-country-isd-code-when-user-select-country-name-from-spinner

Comment: thanks Jignesh. But i am searching some java classes of any inbuilt function or any 3rd party to get country name and isd codes with flags, as there DatePickerDialog in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting telephone country code with Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-country-code-with-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below code it may help you

```
    private ArrayList<String> mCountries = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void getCountryData()
    {
        Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
         for (Locale locale : locales)
         {
                String country = locale.getDisplayCountry();
                if (country.trim().length()>0 && !mCountries.contains(country))
                {
                    mCountries.add(country);
                }
          }
            Collections.sort(mCountries);
    }
```

Comment: hey. Thanks for your code. Its working as i expected. but here i only getting Country Name in Spinner. And what i wanted is to display country calling codes (ISD Codes) in TextView when user select particular country from spinner.  (Eg. India ----> it should display +91)

Answer (score 1):

Just use some simple dropdown Spinner with listview and pass a string array which contains all country names and country calling (ISD). Something like this:

```
<string-array name="CountryCodes" >
<item>93,AF</item>
<item>355,AL</item>
<item>297,AW</item>
<item>61,AU</item>
<item>43,AT</item>
<item>994,AZ</item>
<item>973,BH</item>
<item>880,BD</item>
<item>375,BY</item>
<item>32,BE</item>
<item>501,BZ</item>
<item>229,BJ</item>
<item>975,BT</item>
<item>591,BO</item>
<item>387,BA</item>
<item>267,BW</item>
<item>55,BR</item>
<item>673,BN</item>
<item>359,BG</item>
<item>226,BF</item>
<item>95,MM</item>
<item>257,BI</item>
<item>855,KH</item>
<item>237,CM</item>
<item>1,CA</item>
<item>238,CV</item>
<item>236,CF</item>
<item>235,TD</item>
<item>56,CL</item>
<item>86,CN</item>
<item>61,CX</item>
<item>61,CC</item>
<item>57,CO</item>
<item>269,KM</item>
<item>242,CG</item>
<item>243,CD</item>
<item>682,CK</item>
<item>506,CR</item>
<item>385,HR</item>
<item>53,CU</item>
<item>357,CY</item>
<item>420,CZ</item>
<item>45,DK</item>
<item>263,ZW</item>
</string-array>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17266260/3651574) is the complete list.
And Here are some tutorial ([this](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-spinner-dropdown-displaying-a-list-of-items/) or [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-spinner-dropdown-example/)) for spinners with listview.
and when user will select one from the list then do something like this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long id) {
// Get select item
int sid=spinnerDropDown.getSelectedItemPosition();
your_txtview.setText(""+ countries[sid]);
 }
```

Here you go! Cheers!!