# country code with phone number

Tags: android, country-codes

I can find countryISO from

```
TelephonyManager tManager = 
                 (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryis = tManager.getSimCountryIso();
```

and the phone number I use

```
String tnumber = tManager.getLine1Number();
```

But I want countryISO code with country area code like +91 or +92 (depends on the country).

If I use [libphonenumber.jar](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) will it be straight forward?
Or is there any other code in telephonymanager?

Comment: This question was asked before. Apparently there is no other way. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-country-code-with-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-country-code-with-android

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After 4 Hours of data entry i made a countryCodes realted array file for my requirement hope this will help you too....

just copy paste below code and make data.java file into your package and you can call that array anywhere in your project i also mentioned snippest for how to call it in adpater for ex. spinner

below array code,names,areacode all are in same sequence of index i already verified it and the data in the array is got from wikipedia

here is your solution

**data.java**

```
package your_package_name;



public class data {

    public static final String[] countryNames = { "Afghanistan", "Albania",
            "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antarctica", "Argentina",
            "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
            "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin",
            "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia And Herzegovina", "Botswana",
            "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso",
            "Myanmar", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada",
            "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China",
            "Christmas Island", "Cocos (keeling) Islands", "Colombia",
            "Comoros", "Congo", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Croatia",
            "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti",
            "Timor-leste", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador",
            "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia",
            "Falkland Islands (malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland",
            "France", "French Polynesia", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia",
            "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland",
            "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti",
            "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran",
            "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle Of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Ivory Coast",
            "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati",
            "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho",
            "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
            "Macao", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia",
            "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Mauritania",
            "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova",
            "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", "Mozambique",
            "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Caledonia",
            "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Korea",
            "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama",
            "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcairn",
            "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Romania",
            "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Barthélemy", "Samoa",
            "San Marino", "Sao Tome And Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal",
            "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia",
            "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa",
            "Korea, Republic Of", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Saint Helena",
            "Saint Pierre And Miquelon", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland",
            "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Taiwan",
            "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga",
            "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Tuvalu",
            "United Arab Emirates", "Uganda", "United Kingdom", "Ukraine",
            "Uruguay", "United States", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu",
            "Holy See (vatican City State)", "Venezuela", "Viet Nam",
            "Wallis And Futuna", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe" };

    public static final String[] countryAreaCodes = { "93", "355", "213",
            "376", "244", "672", "54", "374", "297", "61", "43", "994", "973",
            "880", "375", "32", "501", "229", "975", "591", "387", "267", "55",
            "673", "359", "226", "95", "257", "855", "237", "1", "238", "236",
            "235", "56", "86", "61", "61", "57", "269", "242", "682", "506",
            "385", "53", "357", "420", "45", "253", "670", "593", "20", "503",
            "240", "291", "372", "251", "500", "298", "679", "358", "33",
            "689", "241", "220", "995", "49", "233", "350", "30", "299", "502",
            "224", "245", "592", "509", "504", "852", "36", "91", "62", "98",
            "964", "353", "44", "972", "39", "225", "1876", "81", "962", "7",
            "254", "686", "965", "996", "856", "371", "961", "266", "231",
            "218", "423", "370", "352", "853", "389", "261", "265", "60",
            "960", "223", "356", "692", "222", "230", "262", "52", "691",
            "373", "377", "976", "382", "212", "258", "264", "674", "977",
            "31", "687", "64", "505", "227", "234", "683", "850", "47", "968",
            "92", "680", "507", "675", "595", "51", "63", "870", "48", "351",
            "1", "974", "40", "7", "250", "590", "685", "378", "239", "966",
            "221", "381", "248", "232", "65", "421", "386", "677", "252", "27",
            "82", "34", "94", "290", "508", "249", "597", "268", "46", "41",
            "963", "886", "992", "255", "66", "228", "690", "676", "216", "90",
            "993", "688", "971", "256", "44", "380", "598", "1", "998", "678",
            "39", "58", "84", "681", "967", "260", "263" };

    public static final String[] countryCodes = { "AF", "AL", "DZ", "AD", "AO",
            "AQ", "AR", "AM", "AW", "AU", "AT", "AZ", "BH", "BD", "BY", "BE",
            "BZ", "BJ", "BT", "BO", "BA", "BW", "BR", "BN", "BG", "BF", "MM",
            "BI", "KH", "CM", "CA", "CV", "CF", "TD", "CL", "CN", "CX", "CC",
            "CO", "KM", "CG", "CK", "CR", "HR", "CU", "CY", "CZ", "DK", "DJ",
            "TL", "EC", "EG", "SV", "GQ", "ER", "EE", "ET", "FK", "FO", "FJ",
            "FI", "FR", "PF", "GA", "GM", "GE", "DE", "GH", "GI", "GR", "GL",
            "GT", "GN", "GW", "GY", "HT", "HN", "HK", "HU", "IN", "ID", "IR",
            "IQ", "IE", "IM", "IL", "IT", "CI", "JM", "JP", "JO", "KZ", "KE",
            "KI", "KW", "KG", "LA", "LV", "LB", "LS", "LR", "LY", "LI", "LT",
            "LU", "MO", "MK", "MG", "MW", "MY", "MV", "ML", "MT", "MH", "MR",
            "MU", "YT", "MX", "FM", "MD", "MC", "MN", "ME", "MA", "MZ", "NA",
            "NR", "NP", "NL", "NC", "NZ", "NI", "NE", "NG", "NU", "KP", "NO",
            "OM", "PK", "PW", "PA", "PG", "PY", "PE", "PH", "PN", "PL", "PT",
            "PR", "QA", "RO", "RU", "RW", "BL", "WS", "SM", "ST", "SA", "SN",
            "RS", "SC", "SL", "SG", "SK", "SI", "SB", "SO", "ZA", "KR", "ES",
            "LK", "SH", "PM", "SD", "SR", "SZ", "SE", "CH", "SY", "TW", "TJ",
            "TZ", "TH", "TG", "TK", "TO", "TN", "TR", "TM", "TV", "AE", "UG",
            "GB", "UA", "UY", "US", "UZ", "VU", "VA", "VE", "VN", "WF", "YE",
            "ZM", "ZW",

    };
}
```

to set above array from **data.java** file
use below code below code is just sample snippest for your understanding

for countryName

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> countryName = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_con,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data.countryNames);
```

for countryCodes

```
ArrayAdapter<String> countryName = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_con,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data.countryCodes);
```

for countryAreaCodes

```
ArrayAdapter<String> countryName = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_con,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data.countryAreaCodes);
```

Comment: i dont know about libphonenumber i used above code in my app hope it will help you

Comment: This is really good. Not to rely on third party library. Minimalist approach, just requiring a few lines of code once the country list and corresponding codes are available.

Comment: how can I get the index of the country was I choose?

Comment: @Tzahi we are using array. I hope u are aware about how to get index of array elemet :)