# How to get Country Code like +91, +1, +65 from the country name like IN, US, SG in Android?

Tags: android, mobile-country-code

I need to get country code like +91, +1, +65... from the country name like IN, US, SG ... using locale or current Location in android device

i.e suppose if device is in India it returns +91, if device is in US it returns +1, if device is in Singapore it returns +65

I have try so many way but I can't get proper solution.

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-country-code-with-android

Comment: android device are not provided this code, you have add this code manually in local data base

Comment: use `TelephonyManager`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get country ID but not code like +91,+1 and so on

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
CountryID= manager.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();
```

You can prepare your own database for that and manually you need to search from database and then handle such kind of operations

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17266260/3134215) for this kind of data

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. :)

Comment: use this code My Application always show "US" only.

Answer (score 5):

I use this class to map country name to phone prefix:

```
public class CountryToPhonePrefix {

private static CountryToPhonePrefix norway = new CountryToPhonePrefix("Norway ", "47");
private static ArrayList<CountryToPhonePrefix> allList;
private final String countryName;
private final String phoneNumberPrefix;

private CountryToPhonePrefix(String country, String prefix) {
    this.countryName = country;
    this.phoneNumberPrefix = prefix;
}

static synchronized List<CountryToPhonePrefix> getAll() {
    if (allList == null) {
        ArrayList<CountryToPhonePrefix> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Afghanistan", "93"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Albania", "355"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Algeria", "213"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("American Samoa", "1684"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Andorra ", "376"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Angola ", "244"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Anguilla ", "1264"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Antarctica", "672"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Antigua", "1268"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Argentina", "54"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Armenia ", "374"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Aruba", "297"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Ascension", "247"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Australia ", "61"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Australian External Territories", "672"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Austria", "43"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Azerbaijan", "994"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Bahamas", "1242"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Bahrain", "973"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Bangladesh", "880"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Barbados", "1246"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Barbuda", "1268"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Belarus", "375"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Belgium", "32"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Belize", "501"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Benin", "229"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Bermuda", "1441"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Bhutan", "975"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Bolivia ", "591"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Bosnia & Herzegovina ", "387"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Botswana ", "267"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Brazil ", "55"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("British Virgin Islands", "1284"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Brunei Darussalam", "673"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Bulgaria", "359"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Burkina Faso ", "226"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Burundi", "257"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Cambodia", "855"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Cameroon", "237"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Canada", "1"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Cape Verde Islands", "238"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Cayman Islands", "1345"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Central African Republic", "236"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Chad ", "235"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Chatham Island (New Zealand)", "64"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Chile ", "56"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("China", "86"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Christmas Island", "61"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Cocos-Keeling Islands", "61"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Colombia ", "57"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Comoros", "269"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Congo", "242"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Congo, Dem. Rep. of  (former Zaire) ", "243"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Cook Islands", "682"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Costa Rica", "506"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Côte d'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)", "225"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Croatia", "385"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Cuba", "53"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Cuba (Guantanamo Bay)", "5399"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Curaçao", "5999"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Cyprus", "357"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Czech Republic", "420"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Denmark", "45"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Diego Garcia", "246"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Djibouti", "253"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Dominica", "1767"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Dominican Republic ", "1809"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("East Timor", "670"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Easter Island", "56"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Ecuador ", "593 "));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Egypt", "20"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("El Salvador", "503"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Equatorial Guinea", "240"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Eritrea", "291"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Estonia", "372"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Ethiopia", "251"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "500"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Faroe Islands", "298"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Fiji Islands", "679"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Finland", "358"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("France", "33"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("French Antilles", "596"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("French Guiana", "594"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("French Polynesia", "689"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Gabonese Republic", "241"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Gambia", "220"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Georgia", "995"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Germany", "49"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Ghana ", "233"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Gibraltar ", "350"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Greece ", "30"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Greenland ", "299"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Grenada", "1473"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Guadeloupe", "590"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Guam", "1671"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Guantanamo Bay", "5399"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Guatemala ", "502"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Guinea-Bissau ", "245"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Guinea", "224"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Guyana", "592"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Haiti ", "509"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Honduras", "504"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Hong Kong", "852"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Hungary ", "36"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Iceland", "354"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("India", "91"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Indonesia", "62"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Iran", "98"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Iraq", "964"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Ireland", "353"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Israel ", "972"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Italy ", "39"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Jamaica ", "1876"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Japan ", "81"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Jordan", "962"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Kazakhstan", "7"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Kenya", "254"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Kiribati ", "686"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Korea (North)", "850"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Korea (South)", "82"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Kuwait ", "965"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Kyrgyz Republic", "996"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Laos", "856"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Latvia ", "371"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Lebanon", "961"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Lesotho", "266"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Liberia", "231"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Libya", "218"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Liechtenstein", "423"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Lithuania ", "370"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Luxembourg", "352"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Macao", "853"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Macedonia (Former Yugoslav Rep of.)", "389"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Madagascar", "261"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Malawi ", "265"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Malaysia", "60"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Maldives", "960"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Mali Republic", "223"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Malta", "356"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Marshall Islands", "692"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Martinique", "596"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Mauritania", "222"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Mauritius", "230"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Mayotte Island", "269"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Mexico", "52"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Micronesia, (Federal States of)", "691"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Midway Island", "1808"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Moldova ", "373"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Monaco", "377"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Mongolia ", "976"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Montenegro", "382"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Montserrat ", "1664"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Morocco", "212"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Mozambique", "258"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Myanmar", "95"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Namibia", "264"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Nauru", "674"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Nepal ", "977"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Netherlands", "31"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Netherlands Antilles", "599"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Nevis", "1869"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("New Caledonia", "687"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("New Zealand", "64"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Nicaragua", "505"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Niger", "227"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Nigeria", "234"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Niue", "683"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Norfolk Island", "672"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Northern Marianas Islands (Saipan, Rota, & Tinian)", "1670"));
        list.add(norway);
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Oman", "968"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Pakistan", "92"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Palau", "680"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Palestinian Settlements", "970"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Panama", "507"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Papua New Guinea", "675"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Paraguay", "595"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Peru", "51"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Philippines", "63"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Poland", "48"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Portugal", "351"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Puerto Rico", "1787"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Qatar", "974"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Réunion Island", "262"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Romania", "40"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Russia", "7"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Rwandese Republic", "250"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("St. Helena", "290"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("St. Kitts/Nevis", "1869"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("St. Lucia", "1758"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("St. Pierre & Miquelon", "508"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("St. Vincent & Grenadines", "1784"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Samoa", "685"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("San Marino", "378"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("São Tomé and Principe", "239"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Saudi Arabia", "966"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Senegal ", "221"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Serbia", "381"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Seychelles Republic", "248"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Sierra Leone", "232"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Singapore", "65"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Slovak Republic", "421"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Slovenia ", "386"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Solomon Islands", "677"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Somali Democratic Republic", "252"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("South Africa", "27"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Spain", "34"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Sri Lanka", "94"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Sudan", "249"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Suriname ", "597"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Swaziland", "268"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Sweden", "46"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Switzerland", "41"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Syria", "963"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Taiwan", "886"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Tajikistan", "992"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Tanzania", "255"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Thailand", "66"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Timor Leste", "670"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Togolese Republic", "228"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Tokelau ", "690"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Tonga Islands", "676"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Trinidad & Tobago", "1868"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Tunisia", "216"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Turkey", "90 "));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Turkmenistan ", "993"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Turks and Caicos Islands", "1649"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Tuvalu", "688"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Uganda", "256"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Ukraine", "380"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("United Arab Emirates", "971"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("United Kingdom", "44"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("United States of America", "1"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("US Virgin Islands", "1340"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Uruguay", "598"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Uzbekistan", "998"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Vanuatu", "678"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Venezuela", "58"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Vietnam", "84"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Wake Island", "808"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Wallis and Futuna Islands", "681"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Yemen", "967"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Zambia ", "260"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Zanzibar", "255"));
        list.add(new CountryToPhonePrefix("Zimbabwe ", "263"));
        allList = list;
    }
    return allList;
}

public String getPrefix() {
    return phoneNumberPrefix;
}

public String getCountryName() {
    return countryName;
}
```

}