# Area wise locality in Android for India

Tags: android, string.xml

I want to know locality (like state, operator,etc) from the mobile number. You can find the data about mobile number allocation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_telephone_numbering_in_India). The data is huge. I am trying it solve this similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-country-code-with-android) solution by entering the whole data to String file (but that is difficuilt to compile in to string file and parsing is turning out to be bit confusing).

Is there any other alternative way such as online repository to this data. There are various apps in play store and online with similiar feature available (I am doing this task for entrily a different role).

Can some one please point me towards right direction or a small code to parse.

Thank You.

Comment: Why don't you try making a simple database for it?. Make a table for S.NO `Telecom, circle, Category` and `Mobile Operators` and `Circles`.

Comment: Is database more efficient then working with string.xml way?

Comment: It depends. If your data never change, use simple text file like `string.xml`. But if your data have a high probability to change, like adding some data for the new mobile numbers, using database is better. Parsing a file of strings to find a data required a lot of works. Grouping data from a file is another works. So you end up using your times for something that already solved by database. Better to not reinvent the wheel. imho, database is effective though sometimes not efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering my own question).

I did search internet, found a [website](http://www.datayuge.in) which could provide the probably most updated Mobile Number Circle data. But I need it for bulk use (like for all contacts) and it would not have worked.

I found another php script in [github](https://github.com/rahulchordiya/Indian-mobile-circle). (A great thanks to rahulchordiya). As I needed it in for android, string.xml file, I did little modification and can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9T8DKmalQnMT1A4aTdQVnpjMEU/view?usp=sharing). Hope some one finds it useful.