# How do i access local area code in Android from locale?

Tags: android

Hello everyone I am programming a call blocker app. My problem is that I can not compare the incoming phone number to the contact list because the phone numbers in the contact list come in a bad format.

For example:

- Incoming call format yyyxxxxxxxx (local area code)+(phone number) example: **261xxxxxxx**
- Contacts list format xxxxxxxx (phone number)

**This is how i access contact list:**

```
return new CursorLoader(
    getActivity(),   // Parent activity context
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, // Table to query
    new String[]{
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,

    },     // Projection to return
    null,
    null,            // No selection arguments
    null             // Default sort order

    ...
    String phoneNumber = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(loader.getId() == LOAD_CONTACTS_CURSOR ? ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER : CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));

);
```

**This is how i access incoming call:**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
          final Strng incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

How can I get the local area code **not country code**. so I can compare the incoming numbers with those in the contact list?

Best regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting telephone country code with Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-country-code-with-android)

Comment: Im asking to get local area code not country code.

Comment: See the answers below. They tell you how to get local area code.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.